# balanced() binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I need to write a method that determines whether a binary tree is balanced. So first I'm going to have to determine the height of each side of the tree. But I'm having trouble understanding how I am going to count the max length of a subtree, without counting all the nodes in the subtree. This question is very difficult to ask for me, so you guys can understand.

```
// primary method
public int Height()
{
    int h = height( root );
}

// recursive method
private int height( Node x )
{
    if( x == null ) return 0;
    count++;                   
    height( x.left );
    height( x.right );
    return count;           
}
```

Here is my code for calculating the max height of the tree.
But i dont know how to determine just the left or right sides' height,
and this method seems to count the amount of nodes in the tree itself.

Comment: yes i know. but thats why i did'nt ask for the hole balanced tree, just the height and the concept f how to start with the balnced tree. why does my code come out so studip?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742844/how-to-determine-if-binary-tree-is-balanced

Answer (score 1):

This method will not even compile, because of the `return;` statement - you need to return an int.

So, `if(x == null)`, what should you return?  What is the height of an empty tree?

Once you have that figured out, imagine your root has only a left-subtree (`root.right == null`), and you know the height of the left-subtree.  What should the height of the overall tree be?

What if it has only a right subtree?

Now, what if it has both?

Note that you don't need a global counting variable for any of this.

Comment: ok beginners mistake with the first return value. if changed my code there.

Answer (score 1):

The height is 1 + max(left.height(), right.height()).

You should *return* a value instead of *setting* a variable (count, in your case), otherwise you'll go mad.

Comment: but what i dont understand is that left.height() and right.height() will just return 0. how can they return a value if a dont count for one?

Comment: but what i dont understand is that left.height() and right.height() will just return 0. how can they return a value if a dont count for one?

Comment: cuase i say return 0 when a reach a leaf

Comment: Absolutely right about the variable. Global variables and recursion inevitably lead to madness.

Comment: I think you've problems understanding recursion... try to emulate the recursive call on the root node, starting from the bottom of the tree.

Comment: so what your actual compairing to find the max height, is which method( height.left of height.right ) was called the most?

Answer (score 0):

The height of a node is one more than the height of its tallest sub-node (hint: use `Math.max`).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the hints I'll also point out that you really want to use recursion.