# Is the tree created by tsearch() balanced tree?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I am creating a binary using tsearch(). Is the tree created balanced automatically. How can I verify the tree is balanced or unbalanced.

Comment: Create a simple example and look at the tree - what do you see? There is an earlier answer to the general question "is this tree balanced" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742844/how-to-determine-if-binary-tree-is-balanced). Apply it to your tree and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I looked into this some time ago while working on [my own implementation of `tsearch()`](https://github.com/NuxiNL/cloudlibc/blob/master/src/libc/search/tsearch.c). For this API, it makes more sense to use an AVL tree than a Red-Black tree, as performing comparisons through a callback function has a pretty high overhead. AVL trees are more optimally balanced, meaning that the callback is invoked less frequently.

It seems that the definition of `tsearch()` in POSIX does not require any balancing, so unfortunately you cannot assume that these functions perform well. What I observed while looking at some existing implementations:

- glibc implements it as a Red-Black tree.
- musl implements it as an AVL tree, but until 2015-12-08 it contained a bug that caused `tdelete()` to make the tree unbalanced.
- Solaris and the BSDs all seem to share the same implementation that doesn't use any balancing at all.
- FreeBSD 11.0 will no longer use the unbalanced implementation, as it now uses the implementation that I wrote. FreeBSD 11.0 should be released later this year.

Comment: Funny that your implementation seems to be fundamentally incompatible with POSIX as it declares the root as a `posix_tnode *` instead of a `void *` as POSIX mandates.

Comment: That would have been incredibly funny, Chris, but only if it were true.

 Just do a web search for posix_tnode and you will find that one of the top hits is an issue I filed against POSIX to add this data type. It will be part of the eighth edition. It's already in the latest drafts.

Because 'posix_*' is a reserved namespace on POSIX compliant systems, I took the liberty of declaring it unconditionally. To simplify the implementation a bit, I'm declaring it as a struct type instead of 'void', but only as part of the tsearch.c / tdelete.c / ... compilation units.

Comment: This seems like a bad (backwards-compatibility breaking) change in the spec, unless it is required to be typedef'd to void.  The main problem being your code cannot be used as a drop-in replacement for tsearch, as it will break most programs that use it (you cant implicitly convert a `void **` to a `posix_tnode **` if posix_tnode is not void.)

Comment: That’s exactly how it needs to be defined: as void. It’s merely been added to improve the readability of the signatures. I was not claiming that my implementation is a drop-in replacement; it is just an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify by calling `tsearch` on an ordered list of values, and then invoking `twalk`, supplying an *action* that prints out the depth of the tree.  If no tree ordering is taking place then the ordered inserts would have created a list rather than a tree and you will output ascending depth values.

```
void print_depth( const void *nodep, const VISIT which, const int depth )
{
    if( which == preorder || which == leaf ) printf( "%d\n", depth );
}

twalk( root, print_depth );
```

Answer (score 0):

Paddy's answer explains how to verify the tree to be balanced, but does not answer the question whether the tree is balanced or not.

I did what suggested by Paddy, and the answer for me is **yes, it is balanced** (I run GCC 5.1.1 on Fedora, Glibc 2.21)

*(I'm not sure if this also applies on different combination of Operating System, Compiler and Standard Library. If anyone experiments a different answer on their systems, please add an answer here!)*