# What is a recursive function in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a RECURSIVE Function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)

What is a recursive function in PHP? And are there any good tutorials or examples of a PHP recursive function?

Comment: I searched for "recursive function" to find a duplicate, and like every question is about PHP. Why do people think recursive functions are different in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive functions in php are no different than in other languages.  It's simply a function that calls itself.  There's no real need to show examples of recursion in php because it's just so simple.  Take a look at [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).  And here's the famous fibonacci numbers example [in php](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Recursion-in-PHP/2/).