# Repeat SQL select statement until condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

Please see image below: To get the ID's of Mazda's parent categories I would use the following:

```
SELECT `parent_id` FROM `product_categories` WHERE `category_id` = 8
if result is not equal to 0 repeat select statement
```

Is it considered bad practice to loop a SQL select statement until a condition is met? In other words; should I redesign the product categories table?

Many thanks for your advice.

[image: product categories table screendump]

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  in this case it may be warranted to add another field that contains the top-most parent.

This of course introduces redundancy, as the information is already available in the table, but sometimes that is an acceptable tradeoff for performance.

You would add a field for the topsmost parent like this:

```
category_id  category_name  parent_id  top_id
------------ -------------- ---------- -------
1            CARS_          0          1
4            smartphones    0          4
5            Japanese-      1          1
7            Lexus          5          1
8            Mazda          5          1
9            Korean         1          1
10           Toyota         5          1
```

That can be used for getting the topmost parent for a single item, or for getting all items that belong to the same parent, which would be even more complicated with the original layout.

Comment: This might be the way to go for certain purposes, but it wouldn't let me build a parent_id link trail. Suppose the MAZDA product category would contain a subcategory "SUV"(11), then the link trail for this category would be 1 5 8 11.

Comment: @DurianNangka: No, to do that efficiently you would need another table where you would store each link trail as a number of records, where you could use the outermost leaf id to get the trail.

Comment: Thanks. I'll settle 4 the extra table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using this kind of query may complicate processing the results.
I strongly and personally use `recursive functions` instead of query loops.

more info : [What is a RECURSIVE Function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (there are in-built functions for doing the same in PosgreSQL (`with recursive query`)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161