# How to get categories in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to get all categories in wordpress site but separately parent and child categories(in such way it's easily for me to style). In the following code I get parent categories but all children categories are repeated for every parent.
Thanks!

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
$categories_sub = get_categories();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<ul class=" span-5 colborder list_main "> <a href="' . get_category_link(     $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
    foreach ( $cat->parent > 1 and $categories_sub as $cat) {
        $temp=$category->name + '/';
        if(get_category_parents($cat)==$temp) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a><br/>';
        }
        $temp="";
    }
    echo '</ul>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to create HTML list of categories.

### [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

**[Default CSS selectors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Markup_and_Styling_of_Category_Lists)**

Simplest way is to display a list of categories with [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and style the output with default CSS selectors:

```
li.categories
li.cat-item
li.cat-item-7   
li.current-cat 
li.current-cat-parent 
ul.children
```

**[The Walker_Category class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)**

The `Walker` class is for traversing the hierarchical data like menus or categories. It is an abstract class that has four abstract methods `start_el()`, `end_el()`, `start_lvl()`, `end_lvl()`. It is not required to override all abstract methods of the class, only those methods that are needed.

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'walker' => new MyWalker(), 'title_li' => false );
wp_list_categories( $args );

class MyWalker extends Walker_Category {

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" >' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
    }

    function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {}

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '<ul class="span-5 colborder list_main">'.PHP_EOL;
    }  

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    }  
}
```

### [Recursive Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)

Recursive Function is also a good way to traverse through categories. This way you have to manually [get the categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) on each node. Since the [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function returns all the children categories in all subnodes, id of the current category must be passed on to be able to display only the current level categories.

```
get_the_categories();

function get_the_categories( $parent = 0 ) 
{
    $categories = get_categories( "hide_empty=0&parent=$parent" );

    if ( $categories ) {
        echo '<ul class="span-5 colborder list_main">';
        foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
            if ( $cat->category_parent == $parent ) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" >' . $cat->name . '</a><br/>';
                get_the_categories( $cat->term_id );
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i had implemented this code a while ago but you can give it a try..

```
     // get_categories() function will return all the categories
            $upaae_categories = get_categories( array(
             'orderby' => 'name',
             'order' => 'ASC'
            ) );

            foreach( $upaae_categories as $single_cat ) {
             if($single_cat->parent < 1) // Display if parent category and exclude child categories
             {
        echo 'Parent: '.$single_cat->name;
        // now get all the child categories
        $child_categories=get_categories(
            array( 'parent' => $single_cat->term_id )
        );
        if(sizeof($child_categories)>0){ /* this is just for ensuring that this parent category do have child categories otherwise a category cannot be a parent if does not have any child categories*/
        echo '###childs###</br>'
        foreach ($child_categories as $child) {

            echo $child->name.'</br>';
        }// end of loop displaying child categories
        } //end of if parent have child categories

             }
            }
```