# PHP recursive function

Tags: php, recursion

I am new to the concept of recursion. I have created the following example to try and understand recursion. But I am having difficulties and would appreciate your help.

```
function getX($count){
    $count++;
    if($count <= 10){
        $countTemp = getX($count);
        echo $countTemp; //Shouldn't this skipped?
    }
    return $count;
}

getX(0);
```

My confusion is that the above function prints 11, 10, 9, 8....1 but shouldn't the code `echo $countTemp;` be ignored as the statement above it causes recursion? I might be comparing recursion with looping here.

Comment: I guess it's concrete enough to not close that as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php

Comment: Have read this once on SO: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. :)

Comment: *but shouldn't the code echo $countTemp; be ignored as the statement above it causes recursion?* It is not skipped. Recursion here have depth limit, so the control is passed back to place after function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The order of execution is this:

```
if 1 <= 10 true call getX(1)
    if 2 <= 10 true call getX(2)
        if n <= 10 call getX(n)
            if 11 <= 10 false
            // now go all the way back to the getX(0)
            return and echo 11;
        return and echo n;
    return and echo 2;
return and echo 1;
```

#### Visualized on your code:

[image: recursion explained]

#### Explained in words:

- Until `$count` is 11, it will keep calling `getX()` with `$count` (1+2)
- Once your `if` is `false` it will start processing the remaining code, e.g. it will `return $count` (3)
- This then gets assigned and echo'ed as `$countTemp` (4+5)
- Then `$count` is returned again until it's back at the original callee. (5 back to 4)

Answer (score 2):

It is not and should not be ignored, just deferred execution - that's why you are getting numbers in reversed order. When `$count` reaches 11, code in `if` condition is  skipped and value of `$count` is returned to 10th iteration (inside `if`) and echoed as `$countTemp`. In this iteration `$count` was 10 and this is returned to 9th iteration and again echoed as `$countTemp`.