# Recursion and factorial of a number in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

```
<?php  
function factorial_of_a($n)  
{  
    if($n ==0)  
    {  
        return 1;  
    }
    else   
    {    
        return $n * factorial_of_a( $n - 1 );  
    }  
}  
print_r( factorial_of_a(5) );
?>
```

My doubt is:

```
return $n * factorial_of_a( $n - 1 ) ;
```

In this statement - it gives a result of 20 when `$n = 5` and `$n - 1 = 4`. ***But how come the answer 120 when I run it?*** Well, `120` is the right answer... I don't understand how it works. I used `for`-loop instead and it was working fine.

Comment: What is your problem again?

Comment: Well, the problem is *"i don't understand how it works"* `(:`

Comment: Are you asking how recursion works?

Comment: I would answer this question, but unable to now... here's what I did: http://pastebin.com/JKeNyZAH recursion is just revisiting a command in a 'loop' fashion to return a result efficiently. (So reusing code, not having to write something 2 times)

Answer (score 7):

```
factorial_of_a(5)
```

Triggering following calls:

```
5 * factorial_of_a(5 - 1) ->
5 * 4 * factorial_of_a(4 - 1) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * factorial_of_a(3 - 1) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial_of_a(2 - 1) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial_of_a(1 - 1) ->
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```

So, the answer is 120.

Consider reading [*recursive function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) article on wikipedia.

Also, read this related thread: *[What is a RECURSIVE Function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)*

---

> but how come the answer 120 ?

Well, this function will call itself with `$n - 1`, while `$n - 1` is not equals to `0`. When it is, then function actually returns result to the program. So it is not returning result instantly, while argument in larger then `0`. It is called a *"terminate condition"* of the recursion.

Answer (score 4):

It will work in this way..

```
- factorial_of_a(5); 
// now read below dry run code from the bottom for proper understanding
// and then read again from top

   - if n = 0 ; false // since [n = 5]
   - else n*factorial_of_a(n-1); [return 5 * 24] 
   // here it will get 24 from the last line since 4*6 = 24 and pass 
   // it to the value of n i.e. **5** here will make it **120**

     - if n = 0 ; false [n = 4] 
     - else n*factorial_of_a(n-1); [return 4 * 6] 
     // here it will get 6 from the last line since 3*2 = 6 and pass it 
     // to the value of n i.e. **4** here will make it **24**

         - if n = 0 ; false [n = 3] 
         - else n*factorial_of_a(n-1); [return 3 * 2] 
         // here it will get 2 from the last line since 2*1 = 2 and pass it 
         // to the value of n i.e. **3** here will make it **6**

             - if n = 0 ; false [n = 2] 
             - else n*factorial_of_a(n-1); [return 2 * 1] 
             // here it will get 1 from the last line since 1*1 = 1 and pass it 
             // to the value of n i.e. **2** here

                 - if n = 0 ; false [n = 1] 
                 - else n*factorial_of_a(n-1); [return 1 * 1] 
                 // here it will get 1 from the last line and pass it 
                 // to the value of n i.e. **1** here

                     - if n = 0 ; true // since [n = 0] now it will return 1
                     - return 1;
```

Comment: It takes some time to decode your notation, not sure if it helps a beginner...

Comment: ouch actually this is how we use to dry run back in data structures days.. let me see how can I make it more readable.. your edits are welcome too :)

Answer (score 2):

To understand this you need to be clear with the concept of **recursion**.
**Recursion** means calling a function again and again.
Every recursive function has a *terminating case* and a *recursive case*.
Terminating case tells when will the function stop and recursive case calls the function itself again.

In your code the **if condition** $n == 0 marks the terminating case, i.e. do not do any calculation if a number is equal to 0 and return 1.
The else part is the recursive case [ $n*factorial_of_a($n-1) ]

```
Now i will explain how it works for $n = 5 :

Since $n is not equal to 0 then else statement is executed which gives 5 *factorial_of_a(4);

Now factorial_of_a(4) is called which gives 4 * factorial_of_a(3);

Now factorial_of_a(3) is called which gives 3 * factorial_of_a(2);

Now factorial_of_a(2) is called which gives 2 * factorial_of_a(1);

Now factorial_of_a(1) is called which gives 1 * factorial_of_a(0);

Now factorial_of_a(0) is called which gives 1
```

So basically

```
factorial_of_a(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120
```

Hence the result!

Hope it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to bear in mind that his is a recursion
when you call factorial_of_a(5) it will execute this as

```
factorial_of_a(5)  

// 5 * 24
5 * factorial_of_a(4)

  // 4 * 6
  4 * factorial_of_a(3)

     // 3 * 2
     3 * factorial_of_a(2)

         // 2 * 1
         2 * factorial_of_a(1)

             //will return 1 since it is your base condition
             1 * factorial_of_a(0)
```