# PHP - Looping through a mixed array

Tags: php, arrays

Let’s say I have two arrays, one is of keys I require, the other is an array I want to test against.

In the array of keys I require, each key might have a value which is itself an array of keys I require, and so on.

Here’s the function so far:

```
static function keys_exist_in_array(Array $required_keys, Array $values_array, &$error)
{       
    foreach($required_keys as $key)
    {
        //  Check required key is set in the values array
        //          
        if (! isset($values_array[$key]))
        {
            //  Required key is not set in the values array, set error and return
            //
            $error = new Error();

            return false;
        }

        //  Check the value is an array and perform function on its elements
        //
        if (is_array($values_array[$key]))
        {
            Static::keys_exist_in_array($required_keys[$key], $values_array[$key], $error);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the array I want to submit to `$required_keys` CAN look like this:

```
$required_keys = array(
    ‘key1’,
    ‘key2’,
    ‘key3’,
    ‘key4’ = array(
        ‘key1’,
        ‘key2’,
        ‘key3’ = array(
            ‘key1’
        )
    )
);
```

Obviously the problem here is that `foreach` only finds each key, e.g. ‘key4’, rather than the values without their own value, e.g. ‘key1’, ‘key2’, ‘key3’.

But if I loop through with a standard for loop, I only get the values, key1, key2, key3.

What’s a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: When looping check if the value is an array and if so call the function again inside the loop and pass the value (array).

Comment: check the type of element, if it's an array, recurse on that element!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php

Comment: As stated above, the problem is with the looping. Foreach only gives keys, for only gives values. I need both in one loop… Lines 18-21 are the recursive function

Comment: Why do you need both? `key1`, `key2`, etc. are all values. Your array is strange: why is it a mix of an indexed and associative arrays?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $element)` just loops over the values. `foreach($array as $key => $element)` loops over the key and values. But it's not clear which you want in your array. Why do you call the values keys?

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

`$key` is the element of the array, not a key, so you

You shouldn't `return false` as soon as you see a non-matching element, because there could be a matching element later in the array. Instead, you should `return true` as soon as you find a match. Once you find a match, you don't need to keep searching.

You need to do the `isarray()` test first, because you'll get an error if `$key` is an array and you try to use `$values_array[$key]`.  And it should be `isarray($key)`, not `isarray($values_array[$key])`.

You need to test the value of the recursive call. If it succeeded, you can return immediately.

You should only `return false` after you finish the loop and don't find anything.

```
static function keys_exist_in_array(Array $required_keys, Array $values_array, &$error)
{       
    foreach($required_keys as $key)
    {
        //  Check the value is an array and perform function on its elements
        //
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            $result = Static::keys_exist_in_array($required_keys[$key], $values_array[$key], $error);
            if ($result) {
                return true;
            }
        }            
        //  Check required key is set in the values array
        //          
        elseif (isset($values_array[$key]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $error = new Error();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a key => value array with an empty value for the "keys" that don't have a value.

```
$arr = [
    'a',
    'b' => ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 'X'],
    'c' => ['baz' => 'Z'],
    'd'
];

$res = [];
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$vals = array_values($arr);
foreach ($vals as $i => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        $res[$keys[$i]] = $v;
    } else {
        $res[$v] = [];
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 1
            [bar] => X
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [baz] => Z
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning false here is the correct action if you require that ALL the $required_keys exist, because you want it to stop looking as soon as it finds a missing key.

```
static function keys_exist_in_array(Array $required_keys, Array $values_array, &$error)
{       
    foreach($required_keys as $key=>$value)
    {
        //check if this value is an array
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $values_array) 
                || !Static::keys_exist_in_array($value, $values_array[$key], $error);){
                $error = new Error();
                return false;
            }


        }

        //  Since this value is not an array, it actually represents a 
        //   key we need in the values array, so check if it is set 
        //   in the values array    
        elseif (!array_key_exists($value, $values_array))
        {
            //  Required key is not set in the values array, set error and return
            $error = new Error();
            return false;
        }


    }
    //All elements have been found, return true
    return true;
}
```