# Printing a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, formatting

How do I print this array?

```
<?php
    $datos = array(
        array('AZUAY', array('P', 'Q'))
    );
    //print array
    foreach ($datos as $dato1) {
        foreach ($dato1 as $v2) {
            echo $v2;
            foreach ($v2 as $v3)
                echo $v3;
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use recursion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf()` or `var_dump()` as a simple pretty-printer:

```
print_r($datos);
var_dump($datos);
```

Output:

**`print_r()`**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => AZUAY [1] => Array ( [0] => P [1] => Q ) ) )
```

**`var_dump()`**

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "AZUAY" [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "P" [1]=> string(1) "Q" } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$datos = array(
    array('AZUAY', array('P', 'Q'))
);

function printWeirdArray($array)
{
    foreach($array as $i)
    {
       if(is_array($i))
       {
           printWeirdArray($i);
       }
       else
       {
           print $i."-";
       }
    }
}

printWeirdArray($datos);
```

The above code outputs:

`AZUAY-P-Q-`

Good luck!!