# Array Search in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to search something in my SESSION. I think its an array. When I am printing the `$_SESSION["basket"]`, the output will be:

```
[
    ["6"],
    ["5"],
    ["8"]
]
```

These numbers are product ids. I wanna search id on this output. How can I do this?

For ex: I wanna search 8 in `[["6"],["5"],["8"]]`, then output will be true.

Comment: Look for `in_array()`

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work for my codes... @Mihai

Comment: Then you need to show actual output of the array and actual codes.  `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

Comment: If in_array doesn't work, we'll need to see your actual code.

Comment: @TMartin: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is not working because his values are inside a sub-array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is not working is because your values `6`, `5` and `8` are stored inside another array in your main array.

So to search for a value, you could loop through each array with a function:

### Non-recursive (1 level depth search)

```
function searchInArray($array, $value){
    // If the array parameter is not an array and the value parameter is an array, return false
    if(!is_array($array) || is_array($value))
        return false;

    // If the value is found in the main array, return true
    if(in_array($value, $array))
        return true;

    // Loop through each subarray
    foreach($array as $subarray){
        if(in_array($value, $subarray))
            return true;
    }        
}
```

Let's say this is your array:

```
$array = [[6], [5], [8]];
```

And if we var_dump with `var_dump(searchInArray($array, 8));` the result:

```
bool(true)
```

### Recursive (infinite depth search)

With this function, it will search inside each subarray... which is a [recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php):

```
function recursiveSearch($array, $value){
    // If the array parameter is not an array and the value parameter is an array, return false
    if(!is_array($array) || is_array($value))
        return false;

    // If the value is found in the main array, return true
    if(in_array($value, $array))
        return true;

    // Loop through each subarray and make a recursive call
    foreach($array as $subarray){
        if(recursiveSearch($subarray, $value))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So let's suppose this time this is your array:

```
$array = [[6], [5], [8, [9]]];
```

The result:

```
var_dump(recursiveSearch($array, 4)); // false
var_dump(recursiveSearch($array, 8)); // true
var_dump(recursiveSearch($array, 9)); // true
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer, but my output is bool(false), maybe because of "" quotes... Actually, I wanna search and delete what I searched...

Comment: My code: `var_dump(searchInArray($_SESSION["basket"], 8));`

Comment: What's the value of `$_SESSION['basket']`?

Comment: [["6"],["5"],["8"]] this is the value of $_SESSION['basket']

Comment: @MeturJohn I just tried this: `$_SESSION['basket'] = [["6"],["5"],["8"]]; var_dump(searchInArray($_SESSION['basket'], 8));` and it returned true. Are you sure your `$_SESSION['basket']` has the right values?

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be much simpler because your id values all exist in a single column of the multidimensional array.  Use `array_column()` to generate a 1-dimensional array from the first column of values, then call `in_array()` on the array.

Code: (Demo:   https://3v4l.org/UN6PZ )

```
$_SESSION['basket']=[["6"],["5"],["8"]];
var_export(in_array('8',array_column($_SESSION['basket'],0)));
```

Output:

```
true
```