# Foreach all of the nested loops automatically

Tags: php, arrays

guys I am trying to do this kind of loop.

```
$first_ex =
              array(

                 '1st' => array(

                    '1.1' => 'value1',
                    '1.2' => 'value2'
                    // and so on...
                 )
              );
$second_ex =
              array(

                 '1st' => array(

                    '1.1' => array(
                             1.1.1 => 'value'
                             // so on...
                    )
                    '1.2' => array(
                             1.2.1 => 'value'
                             // so on...
                    )

                 )
              );
```

As of now I can only do *array in an array*, but how can I make a code that it will automatically process all of the nested arrays no matter how many nested arrays are in there.

[Note] It does not answer my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a RECURSIVE Function in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php)

Comment: Check out the [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Comment: How can I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
function processArray($array) {
  foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
      processArray($item);
    } else {
      processValue($item);
    }
  }
}

function processValue($value) {
  echo $value;
}

processArray($second_ex);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What I did is close with your code, I can't vote you though.

Comment: @googol8080. Then accept the answer, if it helped you

Comment: @googol8080 you use that tick mark on the side of the answer, and vote the answer up if you like