# create breadcrumbs by self-referencing table

Tags: php, breadcrumbs, self-referencing-table

Is it possible to create breadcrumbs list on my website product page using PHP from table self-referencing structure.

I try to loop from product to get the root category but the result is backward.
or I try to get root category first and loop it but I can't know which one is the correct child to reach the product that I wanted to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there can be different way in different frameworks. I assume you are speaking about core PHP. You can write a [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php) function to get parents from database until you get to the root category. Put the title/id in an array and at the end user [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function to reverse the order of elements in array.