# PHP Iterate over unknown dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm trying to guess how to iterate over multi-dimensional arrays with unknown number of dimensions. I've always done that job statically setting `foreach` statements inside `foreach` statements but I don't know how many statements to set this time because dimensions number is variable. In summary, All I need is to iterate over every element in a parent array that has more arrays as values and those values that are arrays have more arrays as values, and so on...

Comment: _iterate_ and do what?

Comment: want to have some fun doing it? http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver is that relevant? I just want to get the index of every iterated element.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive`, `RecursiveArrayIterator`?

Comment: You can simply create a recursive array function which will manage your looping and recursion quite manually, ie call the same function on array children that are also iterable. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is all that you need:

```
function recur($arr) {
    if (!is_array($arr)) {
        // $arr is the last element
        echo "$arr ";
        return;
    }

    foreach($arr as $ar) recur($ar);
}
```

Comment: Much like I use when drilling through a directory of directories... these little self-calling functions are a wonder.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Technically speaking, they are called recursive function :)

Comment: Well... yes... I was re-iterating in laymen's terms ;) Thats my story and I'm sticken to it.