# Check if value if present in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im working on a way to check if a array contains a value, if not dont run inner code. As the example below there are a couple of languages, but in this case the 'en' language is not present, so if the current translation is 'en' and the 'en' language is not present in the array dont run the second foreach. Using the in_array does not seem to work, if there a function to check if the the valeu is present in the childeren of an array?

the array

```
$arr =array(
    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [language] => de
                    [translation] => blog/beer
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [language] => es
                    [translation] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [language] => fr
                    [translation] => blog/paris-big-city
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [language] => it
                    [translation] => blog/it-slug
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [language] => nl
                    [translation] => blog/nederlands-slug
                )

        )

        [...]//more
)
```

the loop

```
foreach($arr as $items){

    //we need to check if current language is present
    if( in_array('en' , $items) ){
        foreach($items as $item){

         // run code when certain language is present

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need what's called a "recursive function".

Comment: And this gives you a syntax error I presume? `in_array('en' $items)`?

Comment: Okay I will look up 'recusive' as I dont know this.

Comment: no errors but it does not return anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648968/what-is-a-recursive-function-in-php

Comment: @user759235 are you sure? In_array expects two items, only one is given. A string combined with an array. I.e. a comma is missing.

Comment: @Andreas sorry typo, my bad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use array_column to make the in_array work as you expect.

```
$lang = array_column($arr, "language");
foreach($arr as $items){

    if( in_array('en', $lang) ){
        foreach($items as $item){

         // run code when certain language is present

        }
    }

}
```

Array_column grabs all languages in a separate array so that in_array can look in a single dimensional array as it's supposed to.
Multidimensional arrays does not work with in_array.

Edit, missplaced the array_column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk_recursive. It will apply a function recursively to an array and sub-arrays.

[Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and example:

```
public function testArray()
{
    $arr = [
        16 => [
            1 => [
                'language'    => 'de',
                'translation' => 'blog/beer',
            ],
            2 => [
                'language'    => 'en',
                'translation' => 'url/url',
            ],
        ]
    ];

    $match = 'en';
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($key, $value) use ($match) {
        if ($key === $match) {
            // run code when certain language is present
            print "Gotcha \n";
            print $key . "\n";
            print $value . "\n";
        }
    });
}
```

The above example will output:

```
Gotcha 
en
language
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP doesn't want to output the array. This is probably just copied from the manual, right?

Comment: It is copied from the manual. The guy that answered even said so. But his answer is correct. It just needs adjusting to OPs needs.

Comment: @Andrew OP wants to **not** loop if the value is not in the array, this just echos all values.

Comment: @Andreas `You can use array_column to make the in_array work as you expect.` that's your answer. This is @ASOlivieri `You can use array_walk_recursive.`. If you want to criticize others, make sure your answers is properly written and fully explained. Both answers are correct. Literally both.

Comment: It's not the same. Try them and you will see. Create an array and test the codes and you will see. Also on SO you are expected to write answers, not copy paste from manual and say the OP needs to correct it themselves.

Comment: @Andrew got a chance to try it yet?

Comment: @Andreas I posted another answer with ASOlivieri 's answer, but modified.

Comment: I updated with my answer with an example very much like Andrew's only simplified a little further.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and a boolean flag to determine if a certain string exists as a value in an array of undetermined nesting and depth.

This solution simple, easy to read and most importantly scales very well since it doesn't matter how many nesting levels the array has.

```
$arr = [
  16 => [
      1 => [
          'language' => 'de',
          'translation' => 'blog/beer',
      ],
      2 => [
          'language' => 'en',
          'translation' => 'url/url',
      ],
  ]
];

$languageExists = false;
$match = 'en';
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($key, $value) use (&$languageExists, $match) {
   if($key === $match) {
       $languageExists = true;
   }
});

foreach($arr as $items){
    //we need to check if current language is present
    if($languageExists) {
        foreach($items as $item){
            // run code when certain language is present
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a seriously bad solution. You run the complete array once just to find if "en" exists then loop it again.

Comment: The point of this answer is to answer OPs question, thus I'm using parts of his code. Normally you'd do whatever you want to do in the `array_walk_recursive` part or don't use annonymous functions with it. If you want to cherry pick, I'm sure you can. Leaving that aside unless he's running arrays with thousand of entries this isn't even close to any sort of performance hindering. He could probably run another 10 foreaches one after the other and it wouldn't even matter

Comment: That does not make any sense at all. OP asked for a solution to not loop an array twice, and your suggestion is to loop it once and then again. Do you not see the problem with that?