# Regarding recurssive if else block

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how recursive works. Below is a code of If-else block.

```
 public class Test {

     public void test(int count){
         if(count ==1){

        System.out.println("Inside IF");

     }

     else{
              System.out.println("Inside Else");
              test(--count);
              System.out.println("TEST");

       }
           }


      public static void main(String[] args) {

            Test t = new Test();
             t.test(5);
       }


         }
```

The Output for the above code is

Inside Else
Inside Else
Inside Else
Inside Else
Inside IF
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST

Could someone please help me understand why the TEST has been printed 4 times.

Thanks

Comment: I think that someone should be a "book" . A quick help to understand is that , all method calls are mantained in stack until the termination condition is reached, when the pop happens.

Comment: Read http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/techniques/recursion_how.shtml. This will help you.

Comment: It takes 4 decrements to get from 5 to 1.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1949502/18157) and see if it helps explain things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test(5) -> "Inside Else" -> test(4) -> "Inside Else" -> test(3) -> "Inside Else" -> test(2) -> "Inside Else" -> test(1) -> Inside If"

At this point, you were "Inside Else" 4 times.  There are 4 pending PrintLn("Tests") which need to be processed.

"Test"
"Test"
"Test"
"Test"

Answer (score 0):

When you call method b from with method a, method a (the calling method) doesn't just end, it waits until b finishes and then it continues on its merry way. In your case, you're calling the same method each time - each of those methods waits for the method it called to finish. So, when you call `t.test(5)`, it falls into the else block where it calls `test(4)`, so your original call of `t.test(5)` is waiting for `test(4)` to finish. But `test(4)` will call `test(3)` and wait for it to finish. `test(3)` calls `test(2)`, which waits. Then `test(2)` calls `test(1)` and the magic happens.

`test(1)` will fall into the if-block and execute `System.out.println("Inside IF");`, but there's nothing else to execute so it will return. `test(2)` has been waiting for `test(1)` to return, which it now has, so it will continue on and execute the next line of code from where it was at, which is `System.out.println("TEST");`. Nothing else for it to execute, so it returns - to `test(3)`, which was waiting for `test(2)` to return, so another `System.out.println("TEST");`. It returns to `test(4)`: another `System.out.println("TEST");`, and finally to the original `t.test(5)` in main.