# Why do I need to mention the method name? Why not simply (n-1)*n?

Tags: java

Here is the example code, I came across this in Java The Complete reference, 9th edition.

```
// A simple example of recursion. 

class Factorial {           // this is a recursive method 

int fact(int n) { 

    int result;

    if(n==1) return 1; 

    result = fact(n-1) * n;  //This is my question, why not just (n-1)*n?
    return result;
} } 

class Recursion {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 

    Factorial f = new Factorial();

    System.out.println("Factorial of 3 is " + f.fact(3));  //

} }
```

Comment: `(n-1) * n` will compute, well, `(n-1) * n`, which is not the factorial of n.

Comment: It is calculating value recursively. Calling same function within the function.

Comment: Just writting (n-1)*n will execute single time and gives wrong output. We need to have recursive call, so we call same function there

Comment: yeah your question is right if you always pass only 3. Try passing 4, now you will understand why need to call `fact(n-1)*n` instead of `(n-1)*n`

Comment: I suggest you try it and see what the difference is.  You can step through the code in your debugger if you are not sure why it makes a difference.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949454/understanding-basic-recursion

Answer (score 0):

Because otherwise it will not call the function again and will just calculate `n*(n-1)` and exit. For `3` this will do `3x2=6`, which is in fact equal to `3!`. However, if you try it with `4!`, then your change it will return `4x3=12`, when in fact to calculate `4!` it should work out `4x3x2x1=24`.

Comment: Thanks a lot， Plirkee and everyone else! I realize this after I read the next page and check out the sub topic title. It is indeed recursion!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is pretty simple, because most factorial algoritms based on recursive method, that means that fucntion calls itself, if write `(n -1) * n` it will multiply only one time and the result will be wrong(not `n!`). 
There are a lot of articles about recursive methods and how factorial works in particularly. Read those for example:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/recursive-algorithms/a/recursive-factorial
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/