# How Fibonacci Series are generated using 1 variable?

Tags: c, algorithm, fibonacci

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3255159/6073148) to understand how to generate the Fibonacci series using one variable.

```
    unsigned long i = 1;
    printf ("0\n");
    while (((i & 0xffff0000) >> 16) + (i & 0xffff) <= 0xffff) {
        printf ("%d\n", i & 0xffff);
        i = ((i & 0xffff) << 16) | ((i >> 16) + (i & 0xffff));
    }
```

but I am not able to comprehend how it is working?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the number after 5 is 8, not 7.... Also, your text after Tried is hard to understand, sorry

Comment: Looks like you need to read up on [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this is hard?
Written in C, demonstrated on [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/NxOxmI):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n)
{
    return (n == 0 || n == 1) ?  n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    for(n=0; n<10; ++n)
        printf("[%d] : %d\n", n, fib(n));

    return 0;
}
```

I only see 1 variable.
 Does that not meet your requirement?

**Output**

```
[0] : 0
[1] : 1
[2] : 1
[3] : 2
[4] : 3
[5] : 5
[6] : 8
[7] : 13
[8] : 21
[9] : 34
```

If you want to be tricky, use the wonderful expression `n==!!n?n:`

```
int fib(int n)
{
    return n==!!n?n: fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the answer here: [Fibonacci using 1 variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255051/fibonacci-using-1-variable)

as suggested by one of the answers. Although the closed form solution is generally hard to come by unless you know how to solve [Difference equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation)  and solve the fibonacci recurrance

```
Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2
```

I think the better way is the linear algebra.

[image]

The proof can be done easily by induction. Also the matrix multiplication will take O(lgn).