# Cross-platform C++ determining maximim integer value (no headers)

Tags: c++, architecture, cross-platform, metaprogramming

make C++ functions or structs, classes (using meta-programming) determining maximum value for signed and unsigned type, according to compilers architecture. One for signed and second for unsigned numbers.

Requirements:

- no header files
- self adjusting to variable sizes (no stdint.h)
- no compiler warnings about possible overflow

*Clarification:*

*After comment's I am surprised, on reaction for non typical C++ problem. I've learned it's good to stress out, that problem is not homework and not from the moon, but it's practical domain.*

*For all interested in application of this stuff... first of all: it is not homework :). And it's [practical, answerable question based on actual problems that I face - as in SO.FAQ is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) . Thanks you for tips about `climits` etc, but I am looking for "smart piece of code". For sure `climits`, `limits` are well tested and good pieces of code, but they are huge and not necessarily "smart,tricky". We are looking here for smart solutions (not "huge-any" solutions), aren't we? Even thou, `climits` suggestions are ok, as start point. For those interested about area, where including header files is not allowed, and size of source code is relevant, there are few: experiments with compilers, program transformations, preparing problemsets for programming contests, etc. Actually tree of them are relevant to problems I am currently struggling. So I don't think it's [(SO.FAQ)too localized](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close), and I think, it's for sure, question for [(SO.FAQ)enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). If you think that even all of this, there is something wrong with this question, please let me know - I don't want to make mistake again. If it's ok, please let me know, what I could do better to not get it downvoted?*

Comment: So you're not allowed to use `<climits>` or `<limits>`?  Presumably this is a homework question then?

Comment: Pure c++ does not imply no header files.

Comment: What's "pure C++" if you're not allowed to use the standard library? Are templates OK? Functions? Operators?

Comment: Is it allowed to assume two's complement representation ?

Comment: ...copy the source of `numeric_limits`???

Comment: This already exists. Are you trying to re-implement something for a new architecture?

Comment: @keith: The content of `numeric_limits` is probably implemented in a platform-specific manner.

Comment: Thx for responses, I will checkout numeric_limits sources

Comment: @keith.layne: "copy the source of numeric_limits???" - Big disappointment with something like `return __INT_MAX__;`

Comment: @Oli It was a joke.  Did I forget the smiley?

Comment: Actually climits and limits has... hmm... let's say : "specific" definitions in my gcc. I'd like something clear, to put into my source code, which can not use any includes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , actually , it's related with homework I'm preparing to my students, so you are partially right :).Partially, cause hoemwork will be to implement "this&that", but first I want to make sure I understand some "sub-problems" correctly :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signedness could be determined at compile-time if you wish to merge maxSigned with maxUnsigned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> // for pytdiff_t, intptr_t

template <typename T> static inline  bool is_signed() { 
    return ~T(0) < T(1);
}
template <typename T> static inline  T min_value() {
    return is_signed<T>() ? ~T(0) << (sizeof(T)*8-1) : T(0); 
}
template <typename T> static inline  T max_value() { 
    return ~min_value<T>();
}

#define REPORT(type) do{ std::cout\
    << "<" #type "> is " << (is_signed<type>() ? "signed" : "unsigned")\
    << ", with lower limit " << min_value<type>()\
    << " and upper limit " << max_value<type>()\
    << std::endl; }while(false)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    REPORT(char);  // min, max not numeric
    REPORT(int);
    REPORT(unsigned);
    REPORT(long long);
    REPORT(unsigned long long);
    REPORT(ptrdiff_t);
    REPORT(size_t);
    REPORT(uintptr_t);
    REPORT(intptr_t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :). The only issue I had with code , where header files for `uintptr_t`. For `ptrdiff_t` and `intprt_t` it's `<cstddef>`.

Answer (score 5):

Under reasonable assumptions for two's complement representation:

```
template<typename T> struct maxval;

template<> struct maxval<unsigned char>
{
  static const unsigned char value = (unsigned char) ~0;
};

template<> struct maxval<signed char>
{
  static const signed char value = ((unsigned char) ~0) >> 1;
};

template<> struct maxval<unsigned short>
{
  static const unsigned short value = (unsigned short) ~0;
};

template<> struct maxval<short>
{
  static const short value = ((unsigned short) ~0) >> 1;
};

int
main ()
{
  std::cout << (int)maxval<signed char>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Likewise for the rest of the types.

Need to distinguish between signed and unsigned types when determining the max value. The easy way is to enumerate all of them like in the above example.

Perhaps it can be done with a combination of `enable_if` and `std::is_unsigned`, but reimplementing them (no headers!) will still require enumerating all types.

Comment: answering your question above - it's allowed to assume "two's complement representation". Good you've wrote it. Do you know, about nowadays popular architectures that does not use it ? As dar as I know there are x86,x86_64,MIPS,ARM,ATMEL... hmm how do you thing about portability of such assumption?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki, I haven never seen such an architecture. The strangest I've worked with had 32-bit bytes and non IEEE 754 floating point, but still used two's complement for integers.

Comment: You can implement `std::is_unsigned` without enumerating the types. An arithmetic type `T` is unsigned if `T(-1) > 0`.

Comment: Ok chill, it's ok. But, What I was expecting, was something "more tricky" then just enumerating all available types.

Answer (score 4):

For unsigned types, it's simple: `T(-1)` will always be the maximum for that type (-1 is reduced modulo the maximum to fit in the range, always giving the maximum for the type).

For signed integer types, the job is almost as easy, at least in practice: take the maximum unsigned value, shift right one bit, and cast to signed. For C99 or C++11 that *will* work because only three representations for integers (1's complement, signed magnitude and 2's complement) are allowed (and it gives the correct result for all three). In theory, for C89/90 and/or C++98/03, it might be possible to design a conforming signed type for which it would fail (e.g., a biased representation where the bias was not range/2).

For those, and for floating point types (which have no unsigned counterparts), the job is rather more difficult. There's a reason these are provided in a header instead of being left for you to compute on your own...

Edit: As far as how to implement this for in C++, most of the difficulty is in specializing a template for an unsigned type. The most obvious way to do that is probably to use SFINAE, with an expression that will only be legal for a signed type (or only for an unsigned type). The usual for that would be an array whose size is something like `T()-1>0`. This will yield false for a signed type, which will convert to 0; since you can't create a zero-sized array, that attempted substitution will fail. For an unsigned type, the -1 will "wrap" to the maximum value, so it would create a size of 1, which is allowed.

Since this seems to be homework, I'm not going to show an actual, working implementation for that though.

Comment: Does T(-1) not fall into "undefined behavior" for unsigned types, or is that part of the standard?

Comment: @keith.layne: Yes, it is required by the standard.

Comment: In problem statement it's narrowed to integer types, as floating points are "different area" ;).

Comment: It's not template, struct or function... I know about two's complement, and shift operations. The question is how to implement it in C++ in universal <class T> way

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: So, basically you downvoted because I didn't do your homework for you? Get a clue!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Actually it's now my homework, please read other comments. What I didn't like in your case is that I stressed out : ** no compiler warnings about possible overflow** . If you are curious about application of this solution, I am writting LLVM backend, I'd like to make fuzzy approach on small C++ files, which do not use headers.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: A sufficiently stupid compiler might generate arbitrarily stupid warnings, but no sane compiler should be any more likely to produce a warning about anything I've suggested than about `2+2`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I am afraid "For signed integer types(...) take the maximum unsigned value" will not work for "sane" C++ compiler, as there is no way to do generic `template <class T>` function or struct, that creates "`unsigned T`" :/. Is it possible to work around this problem?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: At least assuming you can use C++11 features, look up `make_unsigned`. Lacking that, Boost's [`<type_traits>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp) has the same, though I can't vouch for its compiling without warnings on all compilers (though I think it should on most).

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for tip about `make_unsigned` in C++11. I am just starting with C++11. Works or no - It's good to know about feature, and to read about it - Thanks for all advices and answers :).

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: No problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

This works for unsigned types:

```
template <typename t>
constexpr t max_val() { // constexpr c++11 thing, you can remove it for c++03
  return ~(t(0));
}
```

signed can't be portably found as you can't assume the number of bits and encoding.

Comment: Ok, for unsigned, that was easy. For signed I try metaprogramming approach, like this: [Fibonacci example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751458/fibonacci-function-question/2751647#2751647)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, due to the fact, I was not expecting either: enumerating all types (as Chill), either overflow (as I stated -> I don't want compilers warnings); as some of previous answers consisted. Here is what I've found.

As [Pubby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128498/cross-platform-c-determining-maximim-integer-value-pure-c-no-headers/8128702#8128702) has shown, *unsigned* case is simple:

```
template <class T>
T maxUnsigned(){ return ~T(0); }
```

As [Chill mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128498/cross-platform-c-determining-maximim-integer-value-pure-c-no-headers/8128798#8128798) :

> Under reasonable assumptions for two's complement representation

Here is my meta-programming solution for *signed* case: *(metaprogramming is for omitting overflow compiler warnings)*

```
template<class T, int N> struct SignedMax {
    const static T value = (T(1)<<N) + SignedMax<T, N - 1>::value;
};
template<class T> struct SignedMax<T, 0> {
    const static T value = 1;
};
template<class T>
T maxSigned(){
    return SignedMax<T, sizeof(T)*8-2>::value;
}
```

End example of stuff working

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
//(...)
#define PSIGNED(T) std::cout << #T "\t" << maxSigned<T>() << std::endl
int main(){
    cout << maxSigned<short int>() << endl;
    cout << maxSigned<int>() << endl;
    cout << maxSigned<long long>() << endl;
    cout << maxUnsigned<unsigned short int>() << endl;
    cout << maxUnsigned<unsigned int>() << endl;
    cout << maxUnsigned<unsigned long long>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's resonable approach ? How do you think - will it be cross-platform ? Will it work on ARM, ATMEL etc?

Comment: For what meta-programming ? In order to omit gcc's overflow warinings