# Recursion - Can't Understand This Simple Arithmetic in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am studying old examination papers from my university to be able to prepare for my upcoming exams. Everything is easily understandable from the simplest problems to the most complicated ones. However, I can not, for the life of me, figure the following one out.

```
class k{
    static int g(int n) {
        if (n==0){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2*g(n-1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(g(3));
    }
}
```

Why does this code return 8 as an answer. I get that its basically a power function where the number input is calculated as 2 to the power of that number and hence the answer in this case is 8. But what is really going on. I don't get it. Could someone please explain it in simple English? I'd really appreciate it.

By the way, the question only asks what the output is, not why. But I would feel more comfortable if I knew why it is the way it is.

PS: The reason people are giving answers using 5 as an example is that I had mistakenly put 5 instead of 3 in the code above, which I have corrected now.

Comment: Best way to approach this is to "play computer": Trace out precisely what happens using pencil and paper. Indent your notes per-call. Easiest way to grok recursion.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thank you, the program in the exam paper had 3 as its value, I forgot that I had left the 5 there from my testing. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Thank you for the answers everyone. And I apologize for the confusion about whether it was 5 or 3.

Comment: The temptation to post an answer that linked back to the question was almost impossible to resist, but I guess someone's already done that one :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called recursion. Unless n is ZERO, reduce n by 1 and multiply it by two.

```
return 2 * g(5-1)

return 2 * g(4-1)
```

etc..,

Answer (score 2):

Recursive like everybody said, but there seems to be some confusion about the initial value of n. It's 3 in the example.

```
g(3) = return 2 * g(2);

g(2) = return 2 * g(1);

g(1) = return 2 * g(0);

g(0) = return 1;
```

i.e. 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 = 8

Comment: It's `3` *now*, but it wasn't originally.

Answer (score 1):

You should study on [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). The above example does `2 ^ n`. So for `n=4` you get `16`.

Comment: Actually, it computes 2^n, not 2^(n+1). So, for instance, `g(0) == 1` and `g(1) == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive function that takes a little piece of the arithmetic at a time, and sends along the rest until some ending condition is met.

Take, for instance, the well-known factorial recursive method.

```
public long factorial(int n) {
     return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1)
}
```

If we call `factorial(3)`, we need to do the following.

```
factorial(3) => 3 * factorial(3-1) => 3 * 2 * factorial(2-1) => 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial(1-1)
```

You can see the recursive expansion from here.  Apply this similar tactic to your snippet of code, and you will arrive at why the answer is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

g(1) = 2*g(0) = 2

g(2) = 2*g(1) = 4

g(3) = 2*g(2) = 8

g(4) = 2*g(3) = 16

g(5) = 2*g(4) = 32

g(5) would be 32. g(3) would be 8.