# how does the following code works? finding the depth of the tree?

Tags: c

please explain the working of following code? i am unable to get the recursion.

```
int depth(struct tree *q)
{ 
    int h1,h2;
    if(q==NULL)
       return 0;
    else
    {
       h1=depth(q->left);
       h2=depth(q->right);
    }
    return (max(h1,h2) +1 );
}
```

how does recursion work in the above code? how does h1 and h2 get there value?

Comment: The code will generate at least a warning, since there is a `return` statement that doesn't return anything.

Comment: i might have forgot that! my concern is that how recursion works!

Comment: As for how it works, I suggest you "execute" this on paper for a simple tree, writing down the variable values.

Comment: "To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion

Comment: Errm, where did you get the code? I presume you did not write it yourself, else you might hope to understand how it works. IF you got it elsewhere, was there no explanation? Can you contact the authour?  Must you understand *this* piece of code, or are you just trying to grok recursion in general? (in which case google will show you many, many, many good explanations of recursion). What are you you hoping to achieve here?

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a simple tree with only 3 nodes, 1 root and 2 children

```
      Node R
     /      \
    /        \
Node A      Node B
```

The first call to depth takes Node R as it's argument.

Call 1) `q` is not `NULL` so `depth()` is called for Node R left == Node A

Call 2) `q` is not `NULL` so `depth()` is called for Node A left == `NULL`

Call 3) `q` is `NULL` so return 0;

Call 2) `h1 = 0;`  Now call for Node A right = NULL

Call 4) `q` is `NULL` so return 0;

Call 2) `h1 = 0; h2 = 0; return max(0, 0) + 1`

Call 1) `h1 = 1;`  Now call for Node R right = Node B

Call 5) `q` is not `NULL` so `depth()` is called for Node B left == NULL

Call 6) `q` is `NULL` so return 0;

Call 5) `h1 = 0;`  Now call for Node B right = NULL

Call 7) `q` is `NULL` so return 0;

Call 5) `h1 = 0; h2 = 0; return max(0, 0) + 1;`

Call 1) `h1 = 1; h2 = 1; return max(1, 1) + 1;`

Returns 2.