# Finding the maximum element of an array recursively

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

Consider this code, which computes the maximum element of an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maximum(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n == 1) {
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        int max = maximum(arr, n-1);
        printf("Largest element : %d\n", max);
        return 5; // return arr[n-1] > max ? arr[n-1] : max;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[5] = {5, 23, 28, 7, 1};
    printf("Maximum element of the array is: %d", maximum(array, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the `else` block called four (4) times?

Comment: It's only called 4 times when I run it.

Comment: Sorry I meant 4 times :)

Comment: Why is it surprising that it is called 4 times? What would you expect?

Comment: I expect it to be called only one times. Without the recursive function.

Comment: @Erdem, if you want this to not be recursive, you need to never call `maximum()` from within `maximum()`.

Comment: @mah, I want it to be recursive. In fact I try to understand what is going on. Maybe I am a bit confused :o

Comment: @Erdem: *why* do you expect it to only be called once?

Comment: "I expect it to be called only one times. Without the recursive function." -- That makes no sense. Are you saying you don't expect the recursive call to be made? Why not?

Comment: @JohnBode: because I expect the program flow will go back to the main after the first return in the else block.

Comment: @Erdem look at that else block... before that "first return" (which will return to main), you call maximum() again. This means the "first return" is actually last to be called, in a long list of recursion. You might be able to understand it better if you use a symbolic debugger and step through each line of code.

Comment: @JimBalter: I mean if I comment the recursive function `int max = maximum(ar, n-1);` than it would be called only one times.

Comment: @mah: Thank you very much. This was a nice answer. _This means the "first return" is actually last to be called, in a long list of recursion._ Now I started to figure out what's happening there.

Comment: 'if I comment the recursive function'  - Well yes, of course, if you comment out the recursive call then it isn't made, but it *isn't* commented out. It's obvious to everyone (other than you) that maximum gets called 4 times and why, and it's completely unclear why you think otherwise because you have not in any way said why.

Comment: @JimBalter: Thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion) and mah now I understand why is the maximum gets called 4 times.

Answer (score 3):

The function is recursive, thus it will be called multiple times.

When you first start, n=5.  It will take the else block (n is not 1).
Then, you call maximum again with n-1 (n=4).  Again, the else block is taken.

All told, the function is called 4 times before n reaches 1, whereupon it takes the if block and returns ar[0].

As others have mentioned, the function as written will not return the maximum value of the list.  Curiously, it seems to always return 5 unless the list array size is 1, in which case it returns the value of that element.

Instead, a recursive approach would typically involve splitting the list in half each time, then returning the max of each pair when the list finally broken into pairs of elements.

Answer (score 2):

That is what it is coded to do...

Take a look:

from main we call maximum with 5, then in the else we call the function again with n-1.

```
maximum(array, 5)  //first call from main, hit the else n=5, so recall with n-1
maximum(ar, 4)     //second call from maximum, hit the else n=4, so recall with n-1
maximum(ar, 3)     //third call from maximum, hit the else n=3, so recall with n-1
maximum(ar, 2)     //fourth call from maximum, hit the else n=2, so recall with n-1
maximum(ar, 1)     //fifth call from maximum, n==1 now so do the if and return 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible recursive solution is to compare the previous and the current element.

```
#include <stddef.h>

static int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
int max_array(int *p, size_t size)
{
    if (size > 1)   return max(p[size-1], max_array(p, size-1));
    else            return *p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is called only 4 times.

The recursion rule, as you declared it is:
if n==1, return ar[0] else return the maximum of n-1 elements.

So, the else part is being called for 5, 4, 3 and 2.

However, this recursion is not good enough. As your function is called n-1 times, you only pay the overhead of recursion (stack for example) but you get no advantage over iteration.

If you really want recursion for this task, try to divide the array to 2 and pass each half to the recursive function.

simple pseudo code (not handling odd numbers correctly):

```
int max(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return arr[0];
    return MAX(max(arr, n/2), max(arr+n/2, n/2));
}
```

Comment: How does splitting this in two make anything better? If you were to split the task and then farm each to separate threads, you might pick up a spare processor, but without this it only complicates the code without any benefit.

Comment: I agree, but that was the question. My answer was intended to show that recursion here is meaningless and a better way to use recursion (like in qsort). Anyway, in this solution the stack depth is O(log n)

Comment: I hadn't thought about stack depth... that is a nice benefit.

Comment: Uhm... I've done some bencharks, it seems to require more recursions than the natural solution...

Comment: 1) This fails when `n` is odd.  Instead `MAX(max(arr, n/2), max(arr+n/2, n-n/2))`  2) Better to use `size_t n`.  3) if `MAX()` is a macro, might invoke extra calls.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25414877/2410359

Answer (score 0):

```
int maximum(int ar[], int n)
{
  int max;
  if(!n)
    return ar[n];
  max =maximum(ar,n-1);
  return ar[n]>max?ar[n]:max;
}
```