# How can you find the minimum value in an array using recursion?

Tags: c

I have to write a C code that finds the smallest value in an array using recursion. I've already done it using the for loop, but recursion is trickier . Can someone help me??

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Go as always with recursion : solve the degenerate case (one-element array) then work up the general case.

Comment: For large arrays, you could (conceptually) split them in half and consider each half. Here is the recursion!

Comment: the user has asked the first question here, and get  a down vote!! @angie please post what you've tried and welcom on SO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the maximum element of an array recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285978/finding-the-maximum-element-of-an-array-recursively)

Comment: @Rup i have to do it that way. I have a test in C after 2 weeks, this exercise was in my book and i just can't figure it out.

Comment: @angie I suggest you that don't see the answers. Please find your solution by a simple example like an array with 1 element, then with 2 elements, then 3 elements, and so on. You may find your answer after three steps.

Comment: You might want to look in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735550/find-the-minimum-number-in-an-array-with-recursion

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi - too late.  Answer already provided and copy/pasted into homework.

Comment: @Martin James it's not like that, i need to undertsand that answer, not just copy-paste it

Comment: @angie Great! The bright minds,The bright roads!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple code for finding minimum value using recursion,

```
int rec(int a[],int n)
{
    int min;

    if(n==1)
        return a[0];

    else {
        min=rec(a,n-1);

        if(min<a[n-1])
            return min;
        else
            return a[n-1];
    }

} 

void main()
{
    int i,j,n,a[20];
    printf("enter n :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter values : ");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);  
    }

    printf("\n%d",rec(a,n));

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Congrats - you put more effort into providing a read-made copy-paste straight-to-homework answer than the OP did in writing the question and searching for solutions.

Comment: it's not like that, i need to undertsand that answer, not just copy-paste it

Comment: `void main` is a pain.

Comment: I don't understand this:  min=rec(a,n-1);  I know that a[] is the array, but  i still don't get it.

Comment: For this you need to understand execution of recursive function via program stack .. this link may help http://mooreccac.com/kcppdoc/Recursion.htm

Answer (score 4):

- The minimum of a single item array is that single item (base case or the termination condition).
- The min of an array is the minimum of [the first item, the minimum from the rest (excluding the first item)]

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minimum(int *a_s, int *a_e, int candidate){
    if(a_s == a_e)
        return candidate;
    return  minimum(a_s+1, a_e, *a_s < candidate ? *a_s : candidate);
}

int main(void){
    int array[] = { 1,3,-2,0,-1};

    printf("%d ", minimum(array+1, &array[sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)], *array));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to do OP's homework. Plus, your code would probably be cryptic to a beginner.

Comment: @Quentin We do not _know_ this is homework nor from a beginner (wink, wink, ;-)).  Still, providing an answer that needs work to understand on OP's part looks like a good idea to me in response to such a post.

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer.

Below is a recursive solution that does not chew up the stack.  Estimate max stack depth at O(ln2(n)).  Other solutions look like the maximum stack depth is O(n).

```
int ArrayMin(const int a[], size_t n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    if (n < 0) return 0;  // Handle degenerate ArrayMin( ,0)
    return a[0];
  }
  size_t nhalf = n / 2;
  int left = ArrayMin(a, nhalf);
  int right = ArrayMin(&a[nhalf], n - nhalf);
  return left < right ? left : right;
}
```

Answered after 9 hours, we can assume homework due date is past.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider first element of the array is minimum.
2. Call the function by passing base address of the array and number of elements.
3. Check for any other number is less then the minimum value, if yes assign that value to minimum.
4. For every iteration increment the array address and decrement the no of elements!

Try this code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int min;
int arrfun(int *arr,int n)
{
        if(n){
                if(*arr < min) // check any no is less than minimum.
                        min = *arr; // if yes assign it
        }
        else
                return min; // when n becomes 0 it returns the minimum element
        arrfun(++arr,--n); // recursive call
}

int main()
{
        int arr[]={7,3,9,2,1,6};
        min = arr[0]; // Taking first element is minimum
        printf("minimum is: %d\n",arrfun(arr,6)); // call the function by passing address and no of elements in array
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: you forgot a `return` at the end of `arrfun`. Also I have never seen a recursion using a global variable.