# method to reverse a string using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(reverseString("His"));
}

public static String reverseString(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1) {
        return s;
    } else {
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        return reverseString(s.substring(1)) + c;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me in details how this method works

Comment: Maybe you would like to tell us, where you struggle. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: i want to understand how the method reverseString() works step by step

Comment: See **[Understanding recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/717725/1164465)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose, you have a String "Hello" then it will perform the recursion over the string starting from left to right.

char c = s.charAt(0);

return reverseString(s.substring(1)) + c;

1) for H

c = 'H'

return reverseString("ELLO") + H

2) For E

```
c = 'E'

return reverseString("LLO") + E
```

3) for E

c = 'E'

return reverseString("LLO") + E

4) for L

c = 'L'

return reverseString("LO") + L

5) for L

c = 'L'

return reverseString("O") + L

6)  Since, substring s<= 1

```
return S = 'O'
```

7) Now it will resume back the recursive functions from bottom to top and will concatenate 
all the string s at each level

So, O + L + L + E + H = "OLLEH"

BTW, In java, string reversal is a cakewalk using StringBuilder/StringBuffer. 
e.g. StringBuffer("Hello".toReverse()).toString();

If you are using single threaded and simpler applications, go with StringBuilder

For, concurrent complex applications go with StringBuffer, its Synchrinized.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: It really helps a lot, btw im reversing the string using recursion because i want to learn how recursion works but your explination was really good thank you

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to understand how these types of methods work is to go through them by hand once with a simple example. Let's take the string `"abc"` and consider what happens when we call

```
reverseString("abc")
```

On the first iteration, we consider the `else` block (since `"abc".length()` is not less than or equal to 1). The method returns

```
reverseString("abc".substring(1)) + "abc".charAt(0)
```

which is equivalent to

```
reverseString("bc") + 'a'
```

Now we must consider `reverseString("bc")`. Again, we find ourselves in the `else` block, the method will return

```
reverseString("bc".substring(1)) + "bc".charAt(0)
```

which is equivalent to

```
reverseString("c") + 'b'
```

Evidently, `reverseString("c")` is just `"c"` - so `reverseString("bc")` is `"cb"` which, by above, means that `reverseString("abc")` is `"cb" + 'a'` which gives us `"cba"`, as expected.

---

To summarize, we are essentially doing something like this:

```
reverse("abc")
reverse("bc") + 'a'
reverse("c") + 'b' + 'a'
"cba"
```

With a 4 character string:

```
reverse("abcd")
reverse("bcd") + 'a'
reverse("cd") + 'b' + 'a'
reverse("d") + 'c' + 'b' + 'a'
"dcba"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple.

If your method is called with one char string, it returns the same string and stops. Otherwise it removes the first character to append in the last and call your same method with remaining characters.

Take you example of `His`

This will work like this.

1. Since string length is 3 (>1), it takes `H` out of it to append in the last and calls reverse method with `is`.
2. Since now string length is 2 (>1), it takes `i` out of it to append in the last and calls reverse method with `s`.
3. Now string length is `1` so it will return `s` and recursion will stop.
4. Finally its will start appending your character in **LAST-IN-FIRST-OUT** fashion of their occurance e.g.
      s+i+H
5. This way it will return you the final output as `siH`.

Other way to explain:

```
   reverse("His" ) ->  reverse("is" )+H -> ( reverse("s" )+i)+H -> (s+i)+H ->siH
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Put some print statements in there to see when the `reverseString` method is being called with what arguments.  Here's what you'll get:

```
his
is
s
```

So each time the function recurses, it chops off the first character with `s.substring(1)`.  Then it adds that chopped off first character to the end of the result of reversing that substring.  Using the same above three calls, this looks like:

```
reverse(is) + h
reverse(s) + i
s
```

Notice the final case just returns the single letter "s".  That's called the base case of the recursion, and every recursive function needs one to return a result.

If you substitute the result of `reverse(x)` into the above three calls, you get this:

```
si + h
s + i
s
```

So that's how it works.  To reverse a string, you reverse letters [1-n], then add letter 0 to the end of that.  The only exception is to reverse a one-letter string, which just returns that one-letter string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Intresting function i have not done java in a few years but this shold be how it works.

Check to make sure what we are reversing is more than one character if its not than return it.
Now what we do is we take the fist character and move it to the end of the string, and then we return the rest of the string infront of it.

I in the end the end the string your versering gets to be one character and the first if clausse caues the full string to be returned. :)

Now i am sure there are better ways of solving this function. I am sure java has a reverse string function if you have to make your own for some reason do something like this. also it may not work i did this from memeory and my java is rusty

```
`public static  String reverseString(String s){
    for(int x=s.length(); x>=0; x--) {
      s2 .= s.charAt(x);

    }
    return s2;`
```