# Using the same method declared in the method?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

So been studying for my past exam and come across this question which asks what will the return value be if num = 7? Plugging it into BlueJ tells me 16, what does the func1 do to make it 16? How can the method declared be used again within the method? I searched but hard to find this exact example as it all comes up with just using methods normally.

Thanks,

```
public int func1(int num) 
{
  if ( num <= 2 ) return 1;
  return func1(num – 2) + num;
}
```

Comment: yeah, 16 is correct for num=7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a recursive call to the same function you are using it in.

So, `func1(num – 2)` will invoke the same function - `public int func1(int num)` with `num = num - 2`, until `num >= 2`

So, you recursion goes like this: -

```
func(n)
   calls func(n-2)
      calls func(n-4)
         .. so on
         calls func(1)
            returns 1
         returns 1 + 3 + ... + (n - 4)
      returns 1 + 3 + ... + (n - 4) + (n - 2) 
   returns 1 + 3 + ... + (n - 4) + (n - 2) + n
```

**UPDATE**: - Generalized the above recursion, to let you figure out how it works.

You can go through: - [Recursion - Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Thanks, time to go study some recursion it seems. Makes sense though. Thank you all/

Comment: @user1782493. You should try to understand what happens behind the scene of this recursive process. Then it would be easier for you to work out recursive codes.

Answer (score 3):

This is called *[recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)*. The best way to understand it is to watch it in the debugger, and consider how the sequence of calls will terminate (i.e. *why doesn't it call itself indefinitely*).

(sorry - not giving you a full answer since this is homework/exam related)

Comment: ...or print the value of the variable at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is all about.The method is getting called recursively till a certain exit condition is satisfied. In your case, the exit condition is when the method parameter value hits a value that is <= 2

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion) you can find a good explanation about that.

Comment: I'm disappointed that you didn't link directly to this answer again

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look at (especcially for your exam) is called [Recursion](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html)

The function calls itself with different parameter values, until an internal criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

How can the method declared be used again within the method?

Answer :Calling same method within the method called [Recursion (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

You can do without using recursion using loop

```
public int func1(int num) {
        int res=1;
        while(num >= 2 ) {
            res += num;
            num = num-2;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

But recursion is one of the most important feature to code reuse when you work with Tree, Hierarchy etc.,