# Recursion in c++ Factorial Program

Tags: c++, recursion

hello i have this piece of code that i coded based on some other recursion and factorial programs
but my problem is that i am really confused as to how it stored the value and kept it and then returned it at the end

```
int factorialfinder(int x)
{
    if (x == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }else
    {
        return x*factorialfinder(x-1);
    }
}
int main()
{
  cout << factorialfinder(5) << endl;
}
```

so 5 goes in, and gets multiplied by 4 by calling its function again and again and again, then it gets to one and it returns the factorial answer

why? i have no idea how it got stored, why is return 1 returning the actual answer, what is it really doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)

Comment: Because there has been some... strange voting everyone kindly review the SO guides on up-/down voting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Recursion image from IBM developers website.]

Source: Image is taken from: [IBM Developers website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xslrecur/)

Just take a look at the picture above, you will understand it better. The number never gets stored, but gets called recursively to calculate the output.

So when you call the fact(4) the current stack is used to store every parameter as the recursive calls occur down to factorialfinder(1). So the calculation goes like this: 5*4*3*2*1.

```
int factorialfinder(int x)         
{
    if (x == 1)        // HERE 5 is not equal to 1 so goes to else
    {
        return 1;
    }else
    {
        return x*factorialfinder(x-1); // returns 5*4*3*2*1  when x==1 it returns 1
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The picture is a good start, but the answer misses a critical point: the stack is used to store every parameter as the recursive calls occur down to `factorialfinder(1)`. When the recursive calls "unravel" (return), each parameter is, in turn, pulled from the stack and multiplied by the accumulating product. So storage of each parameter does occur. It's a critical part of recursion. And the recursive calling manages the stack for the programmer.

Comment: @mbratch Thank you for the recommendation. I will edit the answer. I should have mentioned about stack. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Return 1 is not returning the actual answer. It's just returning the answer to calling

```
factorialfinder(1);
```

which happens in your code.

In any program, a call stack is a space in memory that is used to keep track of function calls. Space from this memory is used to store the arguments to a function, as well as the return value of that function. Whenever some function A calls another function B, A gets the return value of B from that space.

A recursive function is nothing special, it's just an ordinary function calling another function (that happens to be itself). So really, when a recursive function F calls itself, it's calling another function: F calls F', which calls F'', which calls F''', etc. It's just that F, F'', F''' etc. execute the same code, just with different inputs.

The expression `if (x == 1)` is there to check when this process should be stopped.
The return value of F''' is used by F''. The return value of F'' is used by F'. The return value of F' is used by F.

In Factorial of some number, the operation is (n) * (n-1) * (n-2) * .... * (**1**).
I've highlighted the 1; this is the condition that's being checked.

Comment: got it "nothing special" lol im still impressed with recursion, seems you can do some hard core math with a few lines getting called recursively. nice answer. at the end i understood with this, i almost thought you were gonna swear here lol FFFF

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function breaks a big problem down into smaller cases.

Going over your program:

```
call factorialfinder with 5, result is stored as 5 * factorialfinder(4)

call factorialfinder with 4, result is stored as 5 * 4 * factorialfinder(3)

call factorialfinder with 3, result is stored as 5 * 4 * 3 * factorialfinder(2)

call factorialfinder with 2, result is stored as 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorialfinder(1)

call factorialfinder with 1, result is stored as 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

in essence it combines the result of a stack of calls to factorialfinder until you hit your base case, in this case x = 1.

Comment: since it all happend under the same instance it kept the value of the previous because thats the power of recursion, so pretty much it goes down the chain one by one by calling its own function, why it kept the answer? im still not sure, im thinking because it all happend with the same variable so when it got to one it still had all the previous calculations in a chain so it got calculated when it hit the case, why did the answer got returned? lol i still dont get it but im getting familiar with its powers

Answer (score 1):

Well, the factorial function can be written using recursion or not, but the main consideration in the recursion is that this one uses the system stack, so, each call to the function is a item in the system stack, like this (read from the bottom to the top):

[image]

Other consideration in the recursion function is that this one has two main code piece:

1. The base case
2. The recursion case

In the base case, the recursive function returns the element that bounds the algorithm, and that stop the recursion. In the factorial this element is 1, because mathematically the factorial of number one is 1 by definition. For other numbers you don't know the factorial, because of that, you have to compute by using the formula, and one implementation of it is using recursion, so the recursive case.

Example:
The factorial of 5, the procedure is: 5*4*3*2*1 = 120, note you have to multiply each number from the top value until number 1, in other words, until the base case takes place which is the case that you already knew.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial(n);

    return 0;
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n > 1)
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Any explanation to the topic might be useful instead of just posting some code.