# recursion and return statement in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I know a little bit about recursion ,but I don;t understand the return statement in which function is calling again and again, could any body help me please to understand this?

Comment: Tried any coding yet?

Comment: This is probably a question you could get answers to on a recursion tutorial. You say you understand a little about recursion, yet you don't understand the most basic principle of it. Try looking at [this tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=recursionPt1) which I found with a simple google search.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement in recursion has different use.

1. To get termination condition or stop recursion from infinite call.
2. Return some data which is used by calling step before current call.

Example:

```
int recursion_demo(int x)
{

// Termination condition
if(x <= 0)
return 0;

print x;

//This statement return sum of 1 to x
return x + recursion_demo(x-1);

}
```

Suppose we call this function as recursion_demo(5). It will print numbers from 5 to 1. Now if we will not have termination condition this recursion will keep running. The last line is recursively calculation sum of numbers from 1 to 5. so it will finally return 15. Internally function call will be in this order:

```
recursion_demo(5);
5 +  recursion_demo(4);
4 +  recursion_demo(3);
3 +  recursion_demo(2);
2 +  recursion_demo(1);
1 +  recursion_demo(0);
```

recursion_demo(0) will terminate this call and their will be no further recursive call. Now it will start roll back.  recursion_demo(0) has return 0
so

1 +  recursion_demo(0) will be 1 + 0; = 1;
1 will return to 2 +  recursion_demo(1); and this will become 2 + 1 and so on and finally `recursion_demo(5)` will return `5+4+3+2+1 = 15`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of recursion where a function is calling again and again in C++.

```
int foo() {         //1.
    return foo();   //2.
}
```

Let's go over an explanation of the code (the comments match up with the numbers).

1. Control arrives at `foo()`.
2. `foo()` has started, and it arrives at the line `return foo();`. Whoops, looks like it is time to run `foo()` again!
3. Go back to line 1. Repeat until the computer runs out of battery, memory, etc.

Comment: just for informatio: calling main in a program isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion contains an if statement ... a base case and a recursive case. for e.g

```
int num(int x)
{
 if (x==0)
   return 0;
 else
   return num(x-1);
}
```

here the num function is once again called in the num function but with a decremented value. The output will be 5,4,3,2,1,0 for x = 5; here the "0" is the **base case** where the function stops ..