# How does the magic flatten method work?

Tags: python

I'm reading "Beginning python, from novice to professional", in which there is a magic flatten function which confused me.

```
def flatten(nested):
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

I know that yield returns an element. So assume I got a list `L = [ 1, [[2]] ]`.
And I call it with this flatten(), like:

```
L = [ 1, [[2]] ]
for i in flatten(L):
    print i

1
2
```

I was really confused, when we call the for loop, won't we triger the flatten(), and we saw the first element `1`, which no doubt will cause `TypeError` in the try block, shouldn't this returned `nested` variable in the except block be the whole list `[1, [[2]] ]`? why would it return `1` instead?

Comment: `yield` is not `return`.

Comment: [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators

Comment: This function combines [generators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/660921) and [recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion). Two concepts that seem to confuse a lot of programmers.

Comment: Don't use this function with a list containing strings or you'll get infinite recursion (because strings are iterable, and their elements are also strings).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps rewriting the function without using `yield` can make it more understandable to you:

```
def flatten(nested):
    res = []
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                res.append(element)
    except TypeError:
        res.append(nested)
    return res
```

In the most basic terms, that is what `yield` does. It 'sends out' a value one at a time from a function. For a more complete explanation, see the answer to [What does the yield keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful to throw in a print statement to see what's going on. Eg,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def flatten(nested, depth=0):
    print "%d: %r" % (depth, nested)
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist, depth+1):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested


def main():
    L = [ 1, [[2]] ]
    for i in flatten(L):
        print "output %s\n" % i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
0: [1, [[2]]]
1: 1
output 1

1: [[2]]
2: [2]
3: 2
output 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what happened here now.

```
def flatten(nested):
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

We still have `L = [1, [[2]]]`, and we call `flatten(L)`.

Now the first element is 1, now we have moved to `for element in flatten(1)`.

As when we call flatten(), and meet TypeError, we'll get `nested` variable, at here, it is 1.

So we got `1`.

And the original L now have only `[[2]]` left in it.

As we called a for loop: `for i in flatten(L)`, things will goes on.

We will now move to `for element in flatten([[2]])`, yes, we got an `yield element` below it, but we have to execute `for element in flatten([[2]])` first and saw what happened.

Now we'll move to `for element in flatten([2])`, it's a temptation to go straight to the `yield element` below it. But hold on, let's go into flatten another time.

Now we have move to `flatten(2)`, it will raise TypeError like flatten(1) do.

So we got `2` this time.

Things explained!