# Can't understand the result of recursion

Tags: java, recursion

i have the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f(4));

    }

    public static int f(int n){
        if(n == 1) return 1;

        return n / f(n - 1);
    }
```

why this code return 4 ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger will help you understand what the code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f(1)` will explicitly return `1`

`f(2)` will give `2/f(1)==2/1==2`

`f(3)` will give `3/f(2)==3/2==1` ([int division](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2))

`f(4)` will give `4/f(3)==4/1==4`

Answer (score 0):

```
f(4) -> 4/f(3)
f(3) -> 3/f(2)
f(2) -> 2/f(2)
f(1) -> 1
```

Subtituting values

```
f(2) -> 2/1 => 2
f(3) -> 3/2 => 1 (since the return value is 1, 1.5 will be converted to 1)
f(4) -> 4/1 => 4
```