# How to find specfic values count from set of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2826 objects. In that objects for example I want to take values like "name" then check that value is presented or not in that object. If presented means I want to take count of value("name") using JavaScript with out using for loop or each function.

In angular I am using:

```
var getunique_count = $filter('filter')(scope.payloadRowCollection,key);
```

But with JavaScript I don't know. So please any one help me to solve this issue or give any example.

Comment: Pretty sure this can't be done without looping through all objects.

Comment: core javascript don't have any inbuild funtion like this.

Comment: The question is unclear, despite it looks like you might want to use .filter or a series of array/object available prototypes. Can you please provide an example serie of objects and the expected output?

Comment: not possible without loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a **deep search** (check recursively in child objects of the current object) of the key "name" in a collection of objects you should use recursion. But still you will have to use loops.

[Understanding Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)