# factorials... I have no idea why this code works

Tags: javascript, recursion, factorial

I came across an exercise on freecodecamp that required writing a code that would return the factorial for a given integer and gave this example: 
    For example: 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120f.

I get how the math works but I couldn't really wrap my head around how to code it until I found something here, n stackoverflow, but without an explination of why it works, that resembled this:

```
function factorialize(num) {
  if(num === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return num * factorialize(num - 1);
  }
}

factorialize(5);
```

I don't really understand how this is iterating through all the integers that are less than or equal to num. Can anybody help explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a recursive function.

Calling factorialize with 5 does the following:

Is 5 equal to 0?  No, so then:

```
return num * factorialize(num - 1);
```

Substituting 5 for num means it is actually returning:

```
5 * factorialize(5-1)
```

So we can simplify that to

```
5 * (factorialize(4))
```

Which then must call factorialize on the second half of the statement to computer the return value.

So you can imagine, factorialize is called again with num = 4.  Since num is not equal to zero, it also returns the same `num * factorialize(num-1)`.  The original statement is now:

```
5 * (4 * factorialize(3))
```

and so it must call itself again... and again... until we have

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorialize(0)
```

which then actually returns a single number - this is called a base case so it doesn't infinitely recurse on itself.  It returns 1.

Resulting in

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```

I would argue the base case should be if (num == 1).  Either way it works

Edit based on comment: The 0 makes sense, it obviously now covers 0 factorial.  Thanks!  With the base case of num == 1 it would only work for factorialize with a parameter num > 0.

Comment: The case is `num == 0` because 0! (zero factorial) is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is called recursion. The basic idea is a function calling itself but passing in a value that gets closer and closer to base can which ends the process. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) and here: [Understanding recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's using something called recursion. Put simply, recursion is what happens when a function calls itself. So in the example, num gets decremented every time it is passed to factorialize, and num gets multiplied by the number passed to factorialize. Try adding a print statement in the else block to see that the number is being decremented with each call

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic implementation of what is known as a recursive function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Recursion works by basically having a function call itself.
So we are multiplying num * (num-1) all the way to 0 (which returns 1).