# Using division in recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following program

```
public static int doSomething(int num){
    if(Math.abs(num) > 9){
        return (1 + doSomething( num / 10));
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(doSomething(333));
}
```

This is how I understand it. If the number is 333. 
`333 / 10` gives me `33`. Since 33 > 9 it runs the recursive loop again giving me `3`. 
After 3 it enters the else condition.

I don't understand why it prints 3 as answer.

I am new to java so still trying to understand the basics.

I don't believe the question is a duplicate. My question is much simpler being a beginner to java. Also the question I believe is using javascript not java.

Comment: It would help me to know why I was downvoted.

Comment: Not your downvoter, but what do you expect?

Comment: _gives me `33 + 1 = 34`_ Where does the 33 come from? It gives you `1 + doSomething(33)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. Still new to java specially recursion. Thank you for pointing out the mistake

Comment: @JeffBenister language doesn't really matter for recursion. Also the duplicate closure is simply that people having the same problem and finding it get redirected to the question with the canonical/best answers that were established already instead of having the same answers with differing quality duplicated over multiple questions, it has no disadvantages for you. Even though I find [Understanding recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/717725) to have the best explanations of recursion in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look, what will return `doSomething()` if `Math.abs(num) < 9`? `1`? yes you are right. Ok lets start.

```
doSomething(333) => 1 + doSomething(33) // 33 not less than 9
                 => 1 + (1 + doSomething(3)) // now 3 is less than 9
                 => 1 + (1 + {1})
                 => 3
```

Comment: Thank you clearing that. I understand how things work recursively (atleast at this level)

Comment: You are welcome. Whenever you confounded by _recursion_ just try to solve it mathematically first, everything will be clear. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion is not on `1 + 33`, but on `33` only, so it's:

```
doSomething(333)
= 1 + doSomething(33)
= 1 + 1 + doSomething(3)
= 1 + 1 + 1
= 3
```