# Loop over multidimensional array and use parent key as prefix

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

When using Eloquent in Laravel 4 or 5, the `$model->with()` methods uses the method as relation name. So if we get a user with his profile, that will return:

```
$user = [
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'Example',
  'profile' => [
    'last_login' => '10-10-1900',
    'another_field' => 'with some data',
    'actions' => [
      0 => 'Logged in',
      1 => 'Logged out',
      2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
    ]
  ]
];
```

I want to flatten the full array and use the key of the relation as prefix, so i.e.:

```
$user = [
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'Example',
  'profile_last_login' => '10-10-1900',
  'profile_another_field' => 'with some data',
  'profile_actions' => [
    0 => 'Logged in',
    1 => 'Logged out',
    2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
  ]
];
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

I also want to flatten multi-dimensional arrays, like this:

```
$user = [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Example',
    'profile' => [
        'last_login' => '10-10-1900',
        'another_field' => 'with some data',
        'actions' => [
            0 => 'Logged in',
            1 => 'Logged out',
            2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
        ],
        'friends' => [
            'friend_one' => [
                'name' => 'Test User',
                'email' => 'test@example.com'
            ],
            'friend_two' => [
                'name' => 'Test User',
                'email' => 'test@example.com'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Into this:

```
$out = [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Example',
    'profile_last_login' => '10-10-1900',
    'profile_another_field' => 'with some data',
    'profile_actions' => [
        0 => 'Logged in',
        1 => 'Logged out',
        2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
    ],
    'profile_friends_friend_one_name' => 'Test User',
    'profile_friends_friend_one_email' => 'test@example.com',
    'profile_friends_friend_two_name' => 'Test User',
    'profile_friends_friend_two_email' => 'test@example.com'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Approach for Original Question (Single Dimension)

```
function flattenParentKey($array, $parentKey)
{
    foreach ($array[$parentKey] as $key => $value)
    {
        $array[$parentKey . '_' . $key] = $value;
    }

    unset($array[$parentKey]);

    return $array;
}
```

Here's an example in the PHP Shell (`php -a`):

```
php > $user = [
php >   'id' => 1,
php >   'name' => 'Example',
php >   'profile' => [
php >     'last_login' => '10-10-1900',
php >     'another_field' => 'with some data',
php >     'actions' => [
php >       0 => 'Logged in',
php >       1 => 'Logged out',
php >       2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
php >     ]
php >   ]
php > ];
php > $user = flattenParentArray($user, 'profile');
php > var_dump($user);
array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Example"
  ["profile_last_login"]=>
  string(10) "10-10-1900"
  ["profile_another_field"]=>
  string(14) "with some data"
  ["profile_actions"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Logged in"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Logged out"
    [2]=>
    string(25) "Signed up for news letter"
  }
}
php >
```

## Recursive Approach for Multi-Dimensional Arrays

As you asked in the comments, and I added to your original question, here's how we'd do this with a nested, multi-dimensional array:

```
$user = [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Example',
    'profile' => [
        'last_login' => '10-10-1900',
        'another_field' => 'with some data',
        'actions' => [
            0 => 'Logged in',
            1 => 'Logged out',
            2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
        ],
        'friends' => [
            'friend_one' => [
                'name' => 'Test User',
                'email' => 'test@example.com'
            ],
            'friend_two' => [
                'name' => 'Test User',
                'email' => 'test@example.com'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

/* Returns true if the specified parameter is an array, is not empty, and is 
 * not a contiguous numeric array).
 */
function isAssociativeArray($array)
{
    if (empty($array) || !is_array($array))
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* Returns true if arrays keys are not numeric or contiguous. */
    return (bool) array_keys($array) !== range(0, count($array) - 1);
}

/* $parentKey will always be null when we first call this function. As
 * it recurses through levels of depth, $parentKey will be passed and
 * appended to.
 */
function flattenChildArrays($array, $parentKey = null)
{
    $outputArray = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        /* If we have a $parentKey, our new key will be "$parentKey_$key" */
        $newKey = (($parentKey) ? $parentKey . '_' . $key : $key);

        if (isAssociativeArray($value))
        {
            /* If our $value is an associative array, we'll want to recursively
             * call ourselves again on $value with our new key as the $parentKey.
             */
            $outputArray = array_merge($outputArray, flattenChildArrays($value, $newKey));
        }
        else
        {
            /* If $value is not an associative array (i.e. just a simple value, or a
             * contiguous numeric array, just use the value as it is in our output
             * array. If we have a parent key (because we're inside 1 or more levels
             * of recursion), use "$parentKey_$key" (see where we define $newKey above).
             */
            $outputArray[$newKey] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $outputArray;
}
```

And an example in the PHP shell:

```
php > $user = [
php >     'id' => 1,
php >     'name' => 'Example',
php >     'profile' => [
php >         'last_login' => '10-10-1900',
php >         'another_field' => 'with some data',
php >         'actions' => [
php >             0 => 'Logged in',
php >             1 => 'Logged out',
php >             2 => 'Signed up for news letter'
php >         ],
php >         'friends' => [
php >             'friend_one' => [
php >                 'name' => 'Test User',
php >                 'email' => 'test@example.com'
php >             ],
php >             'friend_two' => [
php >                 'name' => 'Test User',
php >                 'email' => 'test@example.com'
php >             ]
php >         ]
php >     ]
php > ];
php > var_dump(flattenChildArrays($user));
array(11) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Example"
  ["profile_last_login"]=>
  string(10) "10-10-1900"
  ["profile_another_field"]=>
  string(14) "with some data"
  ["profile_actions_0"]=>
  string(9) "Logged in"
  ["profile_actions_1"]=>
  string(10) "Logged out"
  ["profile_actions_2"]=>
  string(25) "Signed up for news letter"
  ["profile_friends_friend_one_name"]=>
  string(9) "Test User"
  ["profile_friends_friend_one_email"]=>
  string(16) "test@example.com"
  ["profile_friends_friend_two_name"]=>
  string(9) "Test User"
  ["profile_friends_friend_two_email"]=>
  string(16) "test@example.com"
}
php >
```

Recursion can be a difficult topic to understand, as it requires you to follow the program through multiple levels in your head, and it can be easy to lose track of where you are. I recommend taking a simple example, and "stepping through" your recursive function, line by line, commenting what each of the values will be on each level of depth.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion) provide more information about understanding recursion.

Comment: Can use this on a array with more then 10 levels of arrays?

Comment: I dont have a example, but the array changes because i use it on my eloquent data to flatten it all

Comment: I see. You can call it multiple times or in a [recursive](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-recursion/) function.

Comment: And I'm assuming, in your original example, you wouldn't want to flatten `[profile_actions]`, right?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Its just for the values that doesnt have numeric key values. Can you please help me out cause im messing with this for hours now...

Comment: Sure, I can help. I have to run a quick errand, but give me an hour or so :)

Comment: No problem! Check out my edit. This should do what you want for deep, multi-dimensional arrays. I added an example to your original question of what this will do.

Comment: It works pretty well but sometimes it throws the key number in front of the array key, so i.e.: 1_location_city, 2_location_city, do you have a idea how to fix that?

Comment: Oh weird, let me look!

Comment: Is there a way you could `var_dump()` one of the arrays that's causing `1_location_city` and put it on pastebin.com or something (change anything private/sensitive) so i can debug a bit?

Comment: Im sorry for the late response Will, i've been working a lot. I have 2 paste bins. 1 with JSON and 1 as a array. Please use a syntax highlighter to format it well: http://pastebin.com/Uhyxqwqc The array: http://pastebin.com/39ZAqRvv