# Save results to a variable

Tags: python, variables, printing

I created N to combine test1 and test2 making it 1 line 10 digits

 
How do I assign a variable that carries this whole function? So I could use 
`print A`  and it prints N 10 times. I need to use results in future for something else.
Outside of the code below N prints the whole thing just once. I don't want to use

```
print N
print N
print N
print N...
```

Here's the original code

```
for i in range(10):
    test1 = stats.rv_discrete(name='test1', values=(numbers, probability))
    test1_results = test1.rvs(size=8)
    test2 = stats.rv_discrete(name='test2', values=(numbers2, probability2))
    test2_results = test2.rvs(size=2)
    N =  str(test1_results) + str(test2_results)  
   print ''.join(str(v) for v in N)
```

Comment: just put that inside a function with `def x():`

Comment: I tried def before. It's giving me None as an answer

Comment: you have to `return variable` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off writing this as a function instead of storing the information in a variable.

```
def myFunction():
    for i in range(10):
        test1 = stats.rv_discrete(name='test1', values=(numbers, probability))
        test1_results = test1.rvs(size=8)
        test2 = stats.rv_discrete(name='test2', values=(numbers2, probability2))
        test2_results = test2.rvs(size=2) 
        N =  str(test1_results) + str(test2_results)  
    return ''.join(str(v) for v in N)
```

After defining this function you can say `A = myFunction()` and then write `print A`.

Comment: ok now I'm running into other problem. It wont stop printing results until it gives me <code>RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded</code>  I needed 10 results only

Comment: Please read up on what a function is. Also, read about what [recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion) is. You're clearly writing a recursive call in the definition of your function without any base case to end the recursion at. This is not required to solve your problem. If you want more help, provide more detail into your code and what your problem is.