# In a inorder traversal of a binary search tree, where in the code does it traverse up?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I see where how it goes down the tree, but don't see how it traverses back up and onto the right side of the root. Can someone explain? This is fully functional inorder traversal code in Python.

```py
def inorder(self):
    if self:
        if self.leftChild:
            self.leftChild.inorder()
        print(str(self.value))
        if self.rightChild:
            self.rightChild.inorder()
```

Where in this code specifically does it go back in the tree?

Comment: Trace a couple of iterations manually. You'll find that a *return from calling the function* "pops" one level back - to where it was called from. That's the Up you're looking for.

Comment: [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) may help you. It visualizes what the computer is doing step-by-step as it executes the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)

Comment: A return isn't used in this case?

Comment: All python methods without a return statement implicitly return None. Not that that matters because you seem to need to understand recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reaching the end of a function is the same thing as executing `return` which is the same thing as executing `return None`.

For functions that do not return a meaningful value, it is preferred to let execution reach the end of the function rather than place a superfluous `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: Alright, so assuming it reaches the end of the function and returns None, how/where does it run the function again if it isn't being called in the code?

Comment: @Joel: It doesn't have to run the function again; it was *already running*.

Comment: Can you tel me at what line in the above code does it traverse up? Thank you

Comment: @Joel: It never traverses up. Execution at a node is paused while it's waiting for the function traversing the left subtree to finish. When that completes, it continues executing.

Comment: Thanks man, that's what I was looking for that was very helpful.