# Maximum call stack size exceeded. Can't figure out where logic is incorrect

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the `contains` method below. I'm trying to use depth first search to find if the tree contains a value, but I'm not sure what's wrong with my implementation.

```
class Tree {
  constructor(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild(val) {
    this.children.push(new Tree(val));
  }

  contains(val) {
    if (this.value === val) {
      return true;
    } else if (this.children.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
        this.contains(this.children[i].contains(value));
      }
      // When it gets to the leaf node, how do I go back to the previous call? 
      // Do I need to return something here?
    }

    return false; // I may be incorrect on this, but it should return false (execute this line) only when every node has been visited, and there are no more nodes to check. 
  }
};
```

So when I do this:

```
const T = new Tree(100);
T.addChild(50);
T.addChild(40);
T.children[0].addChild(3);

console.log(T.contains(40));
```

I error out because of a maximum call stack error.

Comment: I'm guessing calling `contains()` twice inside a loop that is actually inside `contains()`, becomes too much for the poor browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
this.contains(this.children[i].contains(value));
```

is questionable because as `contains` should return a boolean, it doesn't make sense to then check again if the tree contains that boolean value. Also, the problem is on this line: you are calling `contains` with the exact same arguments (considering `this` as an argument) within itself, meaning it will never stop, resulting in a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error -- a.k.a. stack overflow.

Instead, you should change it to this:

```
if (this.children[i].contains(value))
    return true;
```

That way, the first time it finds the value, it returns. The recursion works as expected because it has a *base case*, i.e. either finding the value in `this.children` or falling off the end of the loop.

Comment: @rvignhne could you explain what you mean by " Also, the problem is on this line: you are calling contains with the exact same arguments (considering this as an argument) within itself, meaning it will never stop, resulting in a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error -- a.k.a. stack overflow."

Comment: @AlanH Since you're calling `contains` on `this`, you are not checking the next level down in the tree as you intended; instead, you are checking the same level of the tree for a boolean value (returned from the second contains call). If `children` does not contain booleans in it, `contains` will never find one -- but it will spawn unlimited copies of itself, each trying to find it, eventually resulting in a stack overflow. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion) has some good examples of recursion.