# Why does only a single statement gets printed in spite of 2 return statement in merge sort function?

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to understand the recursion in merge sort.
    // merge sort

```
var arr = [1,5,3,0];

function mergeSort(arr) {
    if(arr.length == 1)
        return arr;

    if(arr.length > 1) {
        let breakpoint = Math.ceil((arr.length/2));
        // Left list starts with 0, breakpoint-1
        let leftList = arr.slice(0,breakpoint);
        // Right list starts with breakpoint, length-1
        let rightList = arr.slice(breakpoint,arr.length);

        // Make a recursive call
        leftList = mergeSort(leftList);
        rightList = mergeSort(rightList);

        var a = merge(leftList,rightList);
        return a;
    }
}

function merge(leftList,rightList) {
    let result = [];
    while(leftList.length && rightList.length) {
        if(leftList[0] <= rightList[0]) {
            result.push(leftList.shift());
        }else{
            result.push(rightList.shift());
        }
    }

    while(leftList.length)
        result.push(leftList.shift());

    while(rightList.length)
        result.push(rightList.shift());

    return result;
}

console.log(mergeSort(arr));
```

The program works fine, but I do not understand the recursion here. In spite of having multiple return statements, why does the program only print :

```
[0,1,3,5]
```

How does the result get printed, how the recursion is working here?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion

Comment: Your general question is something you should have already researched; you should have a specific question to ask about your lack of understanding.  There are many explanations and illustrations of **mergeSort** on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.  We expect that you've already gone through those.  What *specifically* don't you understand?  I've given you an answer below to address a couple of points you raised ... and voted to close the question, in case others agree with me.

Comment: No matter how many return statements there are in a function only one will get executed because return exits the function. Return does not mean print. It means stop running this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program prints only once, because there is only one output statement in the entire logic flow: when **mergeSort** returns the final, sorted array to the main program, that result comes back as the value for the one and only **console.log** call.

Remember that a **return** sends program control back to the spot that called that instance of the function.  **merge** is called only from the bottom of **mergeSort**.  However, **mergeSort** gets called from the main program and from two places within itself.  For the given example, you will sometimes have *three* instances of **mergeSort** on the stack at the deepest point.  The two higher ones will return to their call points within **mergeSort**; only the original will return to the main program's **log** command.