# How does recursion work concerning scopes of python?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm relentlessly but fruitlessly trying to comprehend how recursion works. I have an example from one tutorial ('Problem solving with algorithms and data structures'). Why is it, that after the recursion has happened, it again makes 5 "additional" steps with the value of the variable rising upward?

**Code:**

```
def tree(branchLen):
    if branchLen >= 5:
        print(branchLen, '#it is pretty understandable')
        tree(branchLen-15)
        print(branchLen, '#stop! Why rising (get backward)?')

tree(75)
```

**Output:**

```
75 #it is pretty understandable
60 #it is pretty understandable
45 #it is pretty understandable
30 #it is pretty understandable
15 #it is pretty understandable
15 #stop! Why rising (get backward)?
30 #stop! Why rising (get backward)?
45 #stop! Why rising (get backward)?
60 #stop! Why rising (get backward)?
75 #stop! Why rising (get backward)?
```

The question has been edited several times to provide more readability (according to remarks). There may be a bit of discrepancies between questions and answers.

Comment: recursion just means the function calls itself a number of times, you can have conditions and parameters in the mix

Comment: This is basic recursion problem. Python has to process through all the lines of the function. So once it called `tree()` inside of `tree()` and it finish the second `tree()` it has to come back to the first one and finish to process to the end of the function. (PS: Your algo does that 5 times because there is 5 call of `tree()`)

Comment: You perform a recursion as long as `branchLen>1`. That means the last "pretty understandable" line calls `tree(0, t)`. At that point you stop the recursion and start to return, and you start to see the second output. Note that in the previous recursions you didn't change `branchLen`, so you see the previous values again.

Comment: If you're stuck on recursion you may simply be stuck on the fact that a function calls itself. Don't think that's something special. Think of it as a call to *some other function*. Presumably you'd understand if `a()` called `b()` which called `c()`? It's no different here, `tree()` calls `tree()` which calls `tree()`; the fact that that's the same function three times is pretty irrelevant. Knowing this, it should be pretty simple to follow the execution path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the [scope rules in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) and concept of recursion. The flow of calling of functions is as follows:

> tree(75, t) --> tree(60, t) --> tree(45, t) --> tree(30, t) -->
>   tree(15, t) --> tree(0, t)

; and then the `if` condition fails and the *scope* returns to the function from whom the function was called, that is the "parent function".
So, after the execution of `tree(branchLen-15,t)` *in the scope of* `tree(15, t)`, the recursive call simply returns and the `print(branchLen, '#stop! Why rising (get backward)?')` line gets executed *in the scope of* `tree(15, t)`, then this function ends and the scope returns to the parent function (which called `tree(15, t)`), viz. `tree(30, t)` and the cycle goes on till the `tree(75, t)` which made the first recursive call completes.
Best way to understand recursion is through stacks, see [here](http://mooreccac.com/kcppdoc/Recursion.htm) for a good explanation.

Comment: Great-great thanks! It's helped make me understand in what way to ponder...