# int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left); int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);

Tags: data-structures

I am new to learning the Binary tree concept.
I'm having a problem with the following:

```
int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left); 
int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);
```

In this piece of code, what is the

> "maxDepth(node->left); "

What is being stored in the **'LDepth'** variable, and the same with the next line, 
after each recursive call - what is being stored in the **'lDepth'** variable?

I would like as specific an answer as possible.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of recursion... A nice explanation you can fine..https://stackoverflow.com/a/717839/5236014

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have given I would say `lDepth` is storing the depth of the `left subtree` and `rDepth` is storing the depth of the `right subtree` where `node` is the root of the tree. This is true for all the subtree recursively.

> "maxDepth(node->left);

You are calling `maxDepth` function recursively to compute the depth of left subtree whose root is `node`.

Comment: i got it what you told ,But what the value like 1,2,3 or etc value is storing the lDepth variable, what is the type of value is strong in lDepth variable and HOW it is storing if it 1,2,3 ...

Comment: @surendraps007 type of the value is `int` and at first, it's computing the depth of smallest subtree and then it's returning the value to compute a bigger subtree with that value recursively.

Comment: what is going inside recursive call that at each iteration the only int value from 0 to so on is going on        WHAT is going inside the recursive call only int value is storing or returning How i get to know

Comment: @surendraps007 just print the value of both variables before making any recursive call. You will see the changes.

Comment: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/dMr6cGKn5f      This where the program  we can see it is printing the 0 ,1, 2 etc But i want to know WHY only 1,2, .. is printing what is going inside the machine or code. PLEASE elaborate what is going inside i know the recursive call method

Answer (score 0):

`maxDepth()` is a recursive function which is called recursively until a `NULL pointer` is encountered indicating the end of the tree. `maxDepth(node->left)` is a recursive call to `maxDepth` function where the subtree is rooted at `node->left`. See the illustration below

```
           node
           /  \
       l_node   r_node
       / \      /\ 
    left  1    3  right
(lDepth)          (rDepth)
```

`l_node=node->left` so the `maxDepth(l_node)` is called. Similarly, `r_node=node->right` so the `maxDepth(r_node)` is called.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i got it what you told ,But what the value like 1,2,3 or etc value is storing the lDepth variable, what is the type of value is strong in lDepth variable and HOW it is storing if it 1,2,3 ...

Comment: @surendraps007 Each node is like a structure. Each node can store a value like 1,2,3 etc., a pointer to its left child, and a pointer to its right child something like this [left, data, right ]. To access the value use node->data, to access the left child used node->left. Similarly for the right child.

Comment: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/dMr6cGKn5f      This where the program  we can see it is printing the 0 ,1, 2 etc But i want to know WHY only 1,2, .. is printing what is going inside the machine or code. PLEASE elaborate what is going inside i know the recursive call method

Comment: Akhilesh Pandey please reply

Comment: Sure brother... Let me have a look into your program.