# I cannot understand this recursion concept

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I found myself stuck in this concept. I just find it very confusing. Can someone enlighten me on how this code is supposed to work?

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (n <= 0) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n];
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Thanks! and sorry if this is so noob of me to ask peace!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

In recursions you call your function in your function until a given requirement is fulfilled.

In this case, your function requires an array as input and the given index where to start (normally this should be the *length of the array - 1*).

F.e. call the function `sum([1,2,3,4], 3)`.

It checks if your index is at position 0, which is not the case.
Then it adds the item at the given index `arr[3] = 4` to the same function, but with an index 1 lower: `sum([1,2,3,4], 3) = sum([1,2,3,4], 2) + 4`

The next function adds its index `arr[2] = 3` to the sum to the same function of index 1: `sum([1,2,3,4], 2) = sum([1,2,3,4], 1)  + 3`. If you fill this in your first function call it becomes: `sum([1,2,3,4], 3) = sum([1,2,3,4], 1)  + 3 + 4`

The next function adds its index `arr[1] = 2` to the sum to the same function of index 0: `sum([1,2,3,4], 1) = sum([1,2,3,4], 0)  + 2`. If you fill this in your first function call it becomes: `sum([1,2,3,4], 3) = sum([1,2,3,4], 0) + 2  + 3 + 4`

In this case of `n = 0`, it returns just the value of the array at index 0. value of the array in that index: `sum([1,2,3,4], 0) = arr[0] = 1`

So the total function adds up to`sum([1,2,3,4], 3) = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10`