# javascript explain this code function call it self

Tags: javascript, call, func

please someone explain this to me

```js
function func(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return x * func(x, n - 1);
  }
}
console.log(func(2, 4)); // 16
```

how do answer is 16

I could not understand more than this
when if is false it going to else
in the return section function call itself
at the first input is the same value as x, ie 2
at the second input is n - 1
when function run again the value of x remains the same as 2 and the value of n becomes 3
that's mean 3 times if is false
in the 4 times if if true and the execution loop ends and show answer in alert
i can not figure out what number is multiplied by x per run or the answer should be the same as 2
because every time the function is executed, shouldn't the value of x be equal to 2?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725/understanding-recursion, you have a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about how recursion works, then I will explain you with this basic flowchart diagram.
[image]

I also edited your JS Code so it will provide you with clarification.

```js
function func(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    let function_returned = func(x, n - 1);
    console.log(x, "*", function_returned, "=", x*function_returned)
    return x * function_returned
  }
}
console.log(func(2, 4));
```

Comment: Thank you all for answers, thank you KayD for your answer

Comment: In fact, the first time is always multiplied by 1 , I used plus and subtraction to see what happens in this case , in plus It gets like this 2+1=3 - 2+3=5 - 2+5=7 - 2+7=9 This means that the answer is wrong unless the first time the number is multiplied by 1 nnd next times plus 2*1=2 - 2+2=4 - 2+4=6 - 2+6=8 or 2*1=2 . 2-2=0 . 2-0=2 . 2-2=0 even for ÷

Answer (score 1):

The function performs exponentiation. So `func(x, n)` is calculating x<sup>n</sup>.

It uses recursion, based on the following principle:

- When n is 1, then x<sup>n</sup> = x<sup>1</sup> = x
- When n > 1, then x<sup>n</sup> = x.x<sup>n-1</sup>

For the second statement we can use the function with arguments x and n-1.

For the concrete example, `func(2, 4)`, this is what happens:

x=2, n=4, so we get in the `else` block and evaluate:

```
2 * func(2, 3)
```

For this nested call of `func` we have x=2, n=3, and again we get in the `else` block for that:

```
2 * func(2, 2)
```

And again we have a nested call, which evaluates to:

```
2 * func(2, 1)
```

...and this final nested call gets into the `if` block and evaluates to:

```
2
```

Now we need to backtrack as each nested function call returns the result to its caller:

- 2 is returned for `func(2, 1)` which turns `2 * func(2, 1)` to 4
- That 4 is returned for `func(2, 2)` which turns `2 * func(2, 2)` to 8
- That 8 is returned for `func(2, 3)` which turns `2 * func(2, 4)` to 16
- And that 16 is what you get in the output

Answer (score 0):

It's a recursive power function. What it does is the following:

1. `2^4 = ?`
2. `2 * 2^3 = ?`
3. `2 * 2 * 2^2 = ?`
4. `2 * 2 * 2 * (2^1) = ?` // at this point we get to `n == 1` and this is where result is just `x` which is `2` in your example. From this point we can start moving "back"
5. `2 * 2 * (2 * 2) = ?`
6. `2 * (2 * 4) = ?`
7. `(2 * 8) = ?`
8. `16 = ?` // 16 is just 16, we're done.
   Your can read a bit about recursion to get a better idea on what is going on.